# Select a row of first non-null values in a sparse table

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, window-functions

Using the following table:

```
A | B    | C    | ts
--+------+------+------------------
1 | null | null | 2016-06-15 10:00
4 | null | null | 2016-06-15 11:00 
4 |    9 | null | 2016-06-15 12:00
5 |    1 |    7 | 2016-06-15 13:00
```

How do I select the first non-null value of each column in a running window of N rows? "First" as defined by the order of timestamps in columns `ts`. Querying the above table would result in:

```
A | B | C
--+---+---
1 | 9 | 7
```

Answer (score 22):

The window function [**`first_value()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) allows for a rather short and elegant solution:

```
SELECT first_value(a) OVER (ORDER BY a IS NULL, ts) AS a
     , first_value(b) OVER (ORDER BY b IS NULL, ts) AS b
     , first_value(c) OVER (ORDER BY c IS NULL, ts) AS c
FROM   t
LIMIT  1;
```

`a IS NULL` evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`. This way, non-null values come first. Order by `ts` (timestamp column like you commented) next and you've got it in a single `SELECT`.

This would be simpler if Postgres supported `IGNORE NULLS`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)

> The SQL standard defines a `RESPECT NULLS` or `IGNORE NULLS` option for
> `lead`, `lag`, `first_value`, `last_value`, and `nth_value`. This is not
> implemented in PostgreSQL: the behavior is always the same as the
> standard's default, namely `RESPECT NULLS`.

One of the few omissions with regard to standard SQL in this area.

We also cannot use a `FILTER` clause. See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)

> Only window functions that are aggregates accept a `FILTER` clause.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=622669bf4828b1cf51fd7c9a5f00a778)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dce83/1)</sub>

Comment: Is there any advantage over `ORDER BY a IS NULL` vs. `order by a nulls first`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `NULLS LAST` in this case. But neither is equivalent. `ORDER BY a IS NULL` only sorts NULL values last, the rest remains *unsorted* - to be sorted by `ts` in the next iteration. `ORDER BY a NULLS LAST` would do too much.

Answer (score 4):

You should define an order (a primary key or something else) to get the FIRST not null value. So I used `ID` column to order rows in your table.

```
select 
(select A from t where A is not null ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
(select b from t where b is not null ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
(select c from t where c is not null ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/170e5/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html). I have Partitioned the result into 2 parts and then used this partition for the `row_number` [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html)

1. having null values
2. having a valid valid

Then, using a basic `case` to get the ones having the `row_number` as `1` and which have a `not null` value in them

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f9fe1/9)

```
SELECT
    max ( CASE
            WHEN a_row_num = 1 AND a IS NOT NULL THEN a
          END ) AS A,
    max ( CASE
            WHEN b_row_num = 1 AND B IS NOT NULL THEN B
          END ) AS B,
    max ( CASE
            WHEN c_row_num = 1 AND C IS NOT NULL THEN C
          END ) AS C
FROM
    (
      SELECT
          a,
          row_number ( ) over ( partition BY a IS NULL ORDER BY ID ) a_row_num,
          b,
          row_number ( ) over ( partition BY b IS NULL ORDER BY ID ) b_row_num,
          c,
          row_number ( ) over ( partition BY c IS NULL ORDER BY ID ) c_row_num
      FROM
          test
    ) AS sub_query
```

**Output:**

```
| A | B | C |
|---|---|---|
| 1 | 9 | 7 |
```

**NOTE:** I have added a `id` field, which helps to know which of the records was first inserted, we use it in ascending order within our window function

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question correctly
as it seems quite simple basically.
Try this query.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/ac585/8

```
WITH t0 AS
(
    SELECT A FROM
    TableName t0
    WHERE (A IS NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY ID ASC
    LIMIT 1
),

t1 AS
(
    SELECT B FROM
    TableName
    WHERE (B IS NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY ID ASC
    LIMIT 1
),

t2 AS

(
    SELECT C FROM
    TableName
    WHERE (C IS NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY ID ASC
    LIMIT 1
)

SELECT t0.A, t1.B, t2.C
FROM
t0
JOIN t1 ON 1=1
JOIN t2 ON 1=1
```