# Subquery to get aggregate with different WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, aggregate-filter

I'm doing this query where I fetch some data I've persisted from an Adwords Report:

```
SELECT "client_name", "customer_id",
  sum(clicks) as clicks,
  sum(impressions) as impressions,
  sum(cost) as cost,
  avg(avg_cpc) as avg_cpc,
  avg(conv_rate) as conv_rate,
  sum(total_conv_value) as total_conv_value,
  sum(converted_clicks) as converted_clicks,
  sum(conversions) as conversions,
  avg(search_impr_share) as search_impr_share,
  avg(cost_converted_click) as cost_converted_click,
  avg(average_position) as average_position
FROM "adwords_daily_account_performance"
WHERE "day" >= ?
GROUP BY "customer_id", "client_name"
```

The table also has a column named `network`. This column can be either 'Display Network' or 'Search Network'. This query aggregates everything from both networks, but I want to add another column to the query for aggregation called `Ctr`.

How do I get this the `Ctr` column where it only aggregates the data where network = 'Search Network' in the same query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a case statement to select the number if the network matches, and a 0 otherwise:

```
SELECT sum( CASE WHEN network = 'Search Network' THEN Ctr ELSE 0 END )
```

Comment: Thank you! It didn't work initially. I think a WHEN clause was missing cause when I wrote: `avg(CASE WHEN network=\'Search Network\' THEN Ctr ELSE 0 END ) as Ctr`

It worked, but I have a problem. It seems that the average is wrong cause it adds 0 every time it isnt the correct network.

Comment: Oh... I'm not sure how to do this with an AVG actually. You could try doing "ELSE NULL", it might skip those in calculating the average. But it could also interpret them as 0, in which case it might not be possible to do in a single query.

Comment: @dadord . . . Just drop the `else` clause.  The `case` will then return `NULL` which is ignored by most of the aggregation functions.  (`NULL` is *not* treated as `0`.)

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres **9.4+** you can use an `aggregate FILTER`:

```
sum(Ctr) FILTER (WHERE network = 'Search Network') AS sum_ctr
```

Details:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)