# Calculate the sum of a field filtered by a window defined on another field

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, aggregate-filter

I have table `event`:

```
event_date,
num_events,
site_id
```

I can easily use aggregate SQL to do `SELECT SUM(num_events) GROUP BY site_id`.

But I also have another table `site`:

```
site_id,
target_date
```

I'd like to do a JOIN, showing the SUM of `num_events` within 60 days of the `target_date`, 90 days, 120 days, etc. I thought this could easily be done using a `WHERE` clause in the aggregate SQL. However, this is complicated by two challenges:

1. The `target_date` is not fixed, but varies for each `site_id`
2. I'd like multiple date ranges to be output in the same table; so I can't do a simple `WHERE` to exclude records falling outside the range from the `event` table.

One workaround I've thought of is to simply make several queries, one for each date range, and then use a view to paste them together. Is there a simpler, better, or more elegant way to achieve my goals?

Comment: Possible post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Your version of Postgres is essential to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like:

```
select sum(case when target_date - event_date < 30 then 1 else 0 end) as within_030,
       sum(case when target_date - event_date < 60 then 1 else 0 end) as within_060,
       sum(case when target_date - event_date < 90 then 1 else 0 end) as within_090    
from event e join
     site s
     on e.site_id = s.site_id;
```

That is, you can use conditional aggregation.  I am not sure what "within 60" days means.  This gives days before the target date, but similar logic will work for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres 9.4 use the [new aggregate `FILTER` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193):

Assuming actual [`date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) data type, so we can simply add / subtracts `integer` numbers for days.
Interpreting "within n days" as "+/- n days":

```
SELECT site_id, s.target_date
     , sum(e.num_events) FILTER (WHERE e.event_date BETWEEN s.target_date - 30
                                             AND s.target_date + 30) AS sum_30
     , sum(e.num_events) FILTER (WHERE e.event_date BETWEEN s.target_date - 60
                                             AND s.target_date + 60) AS sum_60
     , sum(e.num_events) FILTER (WHERE e.event_date BETWEEN s.target_date - 90
                                             AND s.target_date + 90) AS sum_90
FROM   site  s
JOIN   event e USING (site_id)
WHERE   e.event_date BETWEEN s.target_date - 90
                         AND s.target_date + 90
GROUP  BY 1, 2;
```

Also add the condition as `WHERE` clause to exclude irrelevant rows early. This should be substantially faster with more than a trivial number of rows  outside the scope of `sum_90` in `event`.

Comment: What is the advantage of FILTER over using a CASE as suggested by the other answer?

Comment: It's cleaner and faster. The difference won't be big, but test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. It's the SQL standard way implemented in pg 9.4.

Comment: @SRobertJames: Consider the added `WHERE` condition. BTW, this answer is also *correct* as opposed to the currently accepted answer which replaces `num_events` with `1`.