# Comparing 2 time periods in SQL for the same groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to aggregate some data, order it by a specific column, then compare the same data with another time period (e.g. the last week).

An example would be, websites with the most hits this week:

```
url            total hits
www.a.com      10,000
www.b.com      9,0000
www.e.com      5,000
```

This is ordered by hits, but I'd like to get the hits for the *same* urls, but over a different time period e.g.:

```
url            total-hits   total-hits (last week)
www.a.com      10,000       8,000
www.b.com      9,0000       6,000
www.e.com      5,000        6,000
```

The table layout for this data is a list of page-hits e.g.:

```
hit_table:

id     timestamp     url
1      1426470088    www.a.com
1      1426470000    www.b.com
1      1426468015    www.c.com
1      1426467000    www.b.com
....
```

Is it possible to do this in a single SQL query, or do I need to have 2 separate queries for this?

Comment: You should add sample data, as well as desired results.  Or at least a table layout.

Comment: Oops, added a few rows of data. It's essentially just a list of page views.

Comment: Your version of Postgres is essential.

Comment: Using Postgres 9.3.1, but it looks like we're already using some SQLAlchemy for some query generation. Although there's no problem with using explicit SQL queries for some cases if needed.

Comment: In Postgres 9.4 you could use the new aggregate FILTER clause. This question seems very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062193/calculate-the-sum-of-a-field-filtered-by-a-window-defined-on-another-field/29068257

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do what you want using conditional aggregation.  Your question is very vague on the structure of the table, but here is the idea:

```
select url,
       sum(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval '7 day' then 1 else 0 end) as ThisWeek,
       sum(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval '14 day' and
                     timestamp < current_date - interval '7 day'
                then 1 else 0 end) as ThisWeek
from table t
group by url;
```