# Query SQL - Rank employees / Columns with null values

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-filter

I need to fix the following SQL query:

```
SELECT  sep.name AS company_name,
    atnp.name AS employee_name,
    (Case WHEN ip.id_item = 0001 THEN 'Product A'  
        ELSE 'Product B'
        END ) AS product_name,
    (Case WHEN ivcp.id_item = 0001 THEN SUM(ivcp.quantity) 
        ELSE NULL
        END ) AS quantityA,
    (Case WHEN ivcp.id_item = 0002 THEN SUM(ivcp.quantity) 
        ELSE NULL
        END ) AS quantityB
FROM    sale_item AS ivcp
    INNER JOIN stock AS mep ON (mep.id_stock = ivcp.id_stock)
    INNER JOIN sale AS vcp ON (vcp.id_sale = ivcp.id_sale)
    INNER JOIN terminal_sale AS mvtp ON (mvtp.id_terminal_sale = vcp.id_terminal_sale)
    INNER JOIN item AS ip ON (ivcp.id_item = ip.id_item)
    INNER JOIN item_category AS cip ON (ip.id_category_item = cip.id_category_item)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employee AS atnp ON (atnp.id_employee = ivcp.id_employee)
    INNER JOIN sis_company AS sep ON (sep.id_company = mvtp.id_company)
WHERE   mvtp.id_company IN (1)
AND mvtp.date_sale BETWEEN :BeginDate AND  :EndDate
AND DATE(ivcp.date_sale) BETWEEN :BeginDate AND  :EndDate
AND DATE(vcp.data_rec) BETWEEN :BeginDate AND  :EndDate
AND mep.date_sale BETWEEN :BeginDate AND  :EndDate
AND (-1 = -1 OR ivcp.id_employee IN
           (SELECT id_employee FROM team_employee WHERE id_employee = -1))
AND ip.id_category_item = 100
AND ivcp.id_item IN (0002,0001)
AND (ivcp.cancel = 'N' AND vcp.cancel = 'N')
GROUP BY sep.name,
    atnp.name,
    ip.id_item,
    ivcp.id_item
ORDER BY sep.name
```

Results:

```
COMPANY   | EMPLOYEE   | PRODUCT NAME | QUANTITY A | QUANTITY B
Company A | Employee A | Product A    | 1.64       | NULL
Company A | Employee A | Product B    | NULL       | 4.70
Company A | Employee B | Product A    | 84.191     | NULL
Company A | Employee B | Product B    | NULL       | 91.885
```

But I want this:

```
COMPANY   | EMPLOYEE   | QUANTITY A | QUANTITY B
Company A | Employee A | 1.64       | 4.70
Company A | Employee B | 84.191     | 91.885
```

- This query objective is to order some employees sales into a rank of best sellers. The rank will be ordered by the 'product A' and 'product B' sales (ivcp.quantity, id_item = 0001 and id_item = 0002).
- The inner joins are used to match the sales date, item category, employees ids, stock, etc.

I'm working with a Stimulsoft based program to design the report layout, but Im not very used to it. So if it's possible to solve the problem within the query, great!

Comment: Is `-1` that pops up 3 in places supposed to be a parameter in the actual query? Or is it the constant you make it out to be? Also, as *always*, please provide your version of Postgres.

Comment: The -1 is used for optional fields in the report form. If the client don't choose any option for this field, then the query will display all results. You are right when you say that is just noise, it can be removed with any problem. Thx.
[EDIT]: version of Postgres: 9.3

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a simplification of your query. While being at it, I fixed a couple of other things:

```
SELECT sc.name AS company_name
     , em.name AS employee_name
     , SUM((CASE WHEN si.id_item = 0001 THEN si.quantity END) AS quantity_a
     , SUM((CASE WHEN si.id_item = 0002 THEN si.quantity END) AS quantity_b
FROM   team_employee  te
JOIN   sale_item      si USING (id_employee)
JOIN   stock          st ON st.id_stock = si.id_stock
JOIN   sale           sa ON sa.id_sale = si.id_sale
JOIN   terminal_sale  ts ON ts.id_terminal_sale = sa.id_terminal_sale
JOIN   sis_company    sc ON sc.id_company = ts.id_company
JOIN   item           ip ON ip.id_item = si.id_item
JOIN   item_category  ic ON ic.id_category_item = ip.id_category_item
LEFT   JOIN employee  em ON em.id_employee = si.id_employee
WHERE  te.id_employee = -1
AND    st.date_sale BETWEEN :BeginDate AND :EndDate
AND    ts.date_sale BETWEEN :BeginDate AND :EndDate
AND    si.date_sale >= :BeginDate      -- inlude lower border
AND    si.date_sale <  (:EndDate + 1)  -- exclude upper border
AND    sa.data_rec  >= :BeginDate
AND    sa.data_rec  <  (:EndDate + 1)
AND    ts.id_company = 1
AND    ip.id_category_item = 100
AND    si.id_item IN (0002,0001)
AND    si.cancel = 'N'
AND    sa.cancel = 'N'
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 3 DESC NULLS LAST
        , 4 DESC NULLS LAST;
```

- As to **your question**: revert the approach with like demonstrated: ***sum of a `CASE` statement*** instead of the other way round. And adapt `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` accordingly.
  In Postgres 9.4 you would use an aggregate `FILTER`:

  - [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)
- `-1 = -1 OR ...` was just noise. I removed it.
- Weird:

  ```
  AND   (ivcp.id_employee IN 
    (SELECT id_employee FROM team_employee WHERE id_employee = -1))
  ```

  Assuming `-1` is supposed to be a parameter. Either way, I rewrote that into another join.
- Why the leading zeros in `ip.id_item = 0001`? If it's a number then drop the zeros. If it's a string add single quotes to make it a sting literal instead of a numeric literal.
- `id_company IN (1)` is just a convoluted way of saying `id_company = 1`.
- Why the cast `DATE(si.date_sale)`? The name suggests it's already a `date`. Either the name is misleading or the expression is. Either way, this is bad for performance because the expression is not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).
  Assuming it's a `timestamp` I rewrote it to be sargable. Likewise with `sa.data_rec`.
  Also assuming `:EndDate` is a `date`, so we can just add an `integer`: `:EndDate + 1`
- `si.cancel = 'N'` and `sa.cancel = 'N'` look like columns that should really be implemented as [`boolean`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html).
- I adapted `ORDER BY` to your description:

  > The rank will be ordered by the 'product A' and 'product B' sales

  In descending order NULL values come first unless you make it `DESC NULLS LAST`:

  - [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Comment: Your query worked, not 100%. I had to change both 'SUM((CASE WHEN si.id_item = 0001....' because the results were a recursive 'si.quantity' sum with irreal values (got too big). The tips here improved my knowledge, thanks for the help.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta: There is nothing "recursive" here. Probably not the right term? `numeric` is big enough for *any* number ...

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the sums were cumulative, the last employee 'si.quantity' values were more than 1000% of its real value. But few changes worked well in this case.