# Postgres nested SQL query to count field

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a few tables:

```
users - id

users_matches - user_id, match_id, team

matches - id, winner
```

I'd like to count how many wins, losses, and ties a user has. `team` is an integer that could be 1 or 2. `winner` is also an integer, but it can be 1 (team 1 wins), 2 (team 2 wins), or 3 (tie).

I'm not sure how to mix a grouped `count` with a nested query in Postgres.

Comment: Postgres 9.4 I assume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming referential integrity and Postgres 9.4:

```
SELECT *, total - wins - ties AS losses
FROM (
   SELECT count(*) AS total
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE m.winner = um.team) AS wins
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE m.winner = 3) AS ties
   FROM   users_matches um
   JOIN   matches m ON m.id = um.match_id
   WHERE  um.user_id = 123;  -- for one given user
) sub;
```

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause (introduced with Postgres 9.4):

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)