# How do I get counts for different values of the same column with a single totals row, using Postgres SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, postgresql-9.3

So I have a list of children and I want to create a list of how many boys and girls there are in each school and a final total count of how many there are.

My query including logic

```
select sch.id as ID, sch.address as Address, count(p.sex for male) as boycount, count(p.sex for female) as girlcount
from student s
join school sch on sch.studentid = s.id
join person p on p.studentid = s.id
```

Obviously I know this query wont work but I dont know what to do further from here. I thought about nested query but im having difficulty getting it to work.

I found a similar question for postgres 9.4 
[Postgres nested SQL query to count field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715944/postgres-nested-sql-query-to-count-field).  However I have Postgres 9.3.

Final result would be like :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING**
Depending on the data type of the school ID, you may get an error with this union. Consider casting the school ID as a varchar if it is of type **INT**.

```
SELECT
    sch.id as ID, /*Consider casting this as a varchar if it conflicts with 
                     the 'Total' text being unioned in the next query*/
    sch.address as Address,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN p.sex = 'male'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS BoyCount,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN p.sex = 'female'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS GirlCount
FROM
    student s
    JOIN school sch
    ON sch.studentid = s.id
    JOIN person p
    ON p.studentid = s.id
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Total' as ID,
    NULL as Address,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN p.sex = 'male'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS BoyCount,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN p.sex = 'female'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS GirlCount
FROM
    person p
```

Comment: And a `Count(*)` to satisfy OP's requirement: *"and a final total count of how many there are"*.

Comment: @JNevill there we go. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I did get the error but this solved it SELECT  cast('total' as varchar(10))

Comment: @Tito Excellent! Thanks for accepting an answer. I couldn't be 100% certain of the data type of your ID, so I had to throw the warning there. Glad it all worked out!