# Multiple correlated subqueries with different conditions to same table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance

I have two tables:

`orders`

```
| id | item_id | quantity | ordered_on |
|----|---------|----------|------------|
|  1 |    1    |    2     | 2016-03-09 |
|  2 |    1    |    2     | 2016-03-12 |
|  3 |    4    |    3     | 2016-03-15 |
|  4 |    4    |    3     | 2016-03-13 |
```

`stocks`

```
| id | item_id | quantity | enter_on   | expire_on  |
|----|---------|----------|------------|------------|
|  1 |    1    |   10     | 2016-03-07 | 2016-03-10 |
|  2 |    1    |   20     | 2016-03-11 | 2016-03-15 |
|  3 |    1    |   20     | 2016-03-14 | 2016-03-17 |
|  4 |    4    |   10     | 2016-03-14 |    NULL    |
|  5 |    4    |   10     | 2016-03-12 |    NULL    |
```

I'm trying to create a view to show the orders along with their closest stocks `enter_on` like this (I'm using `include_after` and `include_before` to give an overview on which date I want to exclude the item that's preordered, so the stock would reflect correctly.)

`include_after` is always going to be the stock that came in but not expired yet, if expired, show NULL, `include_before` will always show the next incoming stock `enter_on`, unless there's an `expire_on` that's earlier than the next `enter_on`.

```
| item_id | quantity | ordered_on | include_after | include_before |
|---------|----------|------------|---------------|----------------|
|    1    |    2     | 2016-03-09 |  2016-03-07   |   2016-03-10   |
|    1    |    2     | 2016-03-12 |  2016-03-11   |   2016-03-14   |
|    4    |    3     | 2016-03-13 |  2016-03-12   |   2016-03-14   |
|    4    |    3     | 2016-03-15 |  2016-03-14   |      NULL      |
```

So this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
  o.item_id, o.quantity, o.order_on, (
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(s.enter_on), NULL::DATE)
    FROM stocks s
    WHERE s.enter_on <= o.order_on AND s.item_id = o.item_id
  ) as include_after, (
    SELECT COALESCE(MIN(s.enter_on), NULL::DATE)
    FROM stocks s
    WHERE s.enter_on > o.order_on AND s.item_id = o.item_id
  ) as include_before
FROM
  orders o;
```

It works fine (I haven't included the `expire_on` part), but I'm worrying about performance issue for using two subqueries in the select.

Does anyone have some alternative suggestions?

UPDATE

> I'm using Postgresql 9.4 (Can't add anymore tags)
>
> the actual problem is way more complicated than I stated, it's a lot of tables joined together and views, I shrunk it down to just one table to grasp the concept if there are alternatives

Comment: Actual table definitions would be much more useful. Ideally, complete `CREATE TABLE` statements showing data types and constraints. And, obviously, your version of Postgres.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should worry about performance when the situation arises.   For the example that you provided, an index on `stocks(item_id, enter_on, expire_on)` should be sufficient.  Then you might actually want two indexes:  `stocks(item_id, enter_on desc, expire_on)`.

If the performance is not sufficient, you have two choices.  One is a GIST index for ranges.  ([Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns) is an interesting discussion of the issue.)   The second is an alternative query formulation.

However, I would attempt to optimize the query until there is enough data to show a performance problem.  Solutions on smaller amounts of data just might not scale well.

Answer (score 1):

Discussing the query you *display*, also not considering `expire_on`.

#### `COALESCE` for a correlated subquery

First off, the expression <strike>`COALESCE(anything, NULL)`</strike> *never* makes sense. You would replace `NULL` with `NULL`.

Aggregate functions like `max()` return `NULL` anyway (preventing "no row"), even if no qualifying row is found. (The exception being `count()`, which returns `0`).

A correlated subquery that would return "no row" (like the variant with `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` I demonstrate below) defaults to `NULL` for the column value.

So, if you wanted to use `COALESCE` in this context, you would wrap it around the correlated subquery as a whole - and provide a default for `NULL`.

#### Query

> I'm worrying about performance issue for using two subqueries in the select.

**It depends.**

**If** there are only *few* rows per `item_id` in table `stocks` and / or only an index on `stocks(item_id)`, then it would make sense to merge the two correlated subqueries into one `LATERAL` subquery with conditional aggregates:

```sql
SELECT o.item_id, o.quantity, o.order_on
     , s.include_after, s.include_before
FROM  orders o
    , LATERAL (
   SELECT max(enter_on) FILTER (WHERE enter_on <= o.order_on) AS include_after
        , min(enter_on) FILTER (WHERE enter_on >  o.order_on) AS include_before
   FROM   stocks
   WHERE  item_id = o.item_id
   ) s;
```

Since the subquery returns a row in any case due to the aggregate functions, a simple `CROSS JOIN` is fine. Else you might want to use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL (...) ON true`. See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

The aggregate `FILTER` clause requires Postgres 9.4+. There are alternatives for older versions. See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

**If**, on the other hand, you have *many* rows per `item_id` in table `stocks` *and* an index `ON stocks (item_id, enter_on)`, your query might still be faster. Or this slightly adapted version (test both!):

```sql
SELECT o.item_id, o.quantity, o.order_on
   , (SELECT s.enter_on
      FROM   stocks s
      WHERE  s.item_id = o.item_id
      AND    s.enter_on <= o.order_on
      ORDER  BY 1 DESC NULLS LAST
      LIMIT  1) AS include_after
   , (SELECT s.enter_on
      FROM   stocks s
      WHERE  s.item_id = o.item_id
      AND    s.enter_on > o.order_on
      ORDER  BY 1
      LIMIT  1) AS include_before
FROM  orders o;
```

Because both correlated subqueries can be resolved to a single index lookup each.

To optimize performance, you might need a 2nd index on `stocks(item_id, enter_on DESC NULLS LAST)`. But don't create specialized indexes unless you actually need to squeeze out more read performance for this query (key word: *premature optimization*).

Detailed discussion in this related answer:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, the actual problem is way more complicated than I stated, it's a lot of tables joined together and views, I shrunk it down to just one table to grasp the concept if there are alternatives, looks like I have a lot of readings to do.