# Find rows where a minimum number of columns match a pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a schema like the following (just an example):

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id    int primary key
, text1 text
, text2 text
, text3 text
, text4 text
, text5 text
, text6 text
);
```

Question:

I'm trying to run a pattern matching search on the 6 text columns using the `~*` operator. Can I query the example table by the count of appearances of my pattern in the 6 columns?

Example:

I want to find all rows that have said keyword in at least 3 of the 6 text columns. Whichever of those 6 columns does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a number of matches in the simple way like this:

```
insert into example values (1, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

select 
    id, 
    (text1 ~* 'a')::int+ (text2 ~* 'a')::int+ 
    (text3 ~* 'a')::int+ (text4 ~* 'a')::int+ 
    (text5 ~* 'a')::int+ (text6 ~* 'a')::int as matches
from example;

 id | matches 
----+---------
  1 |       3
```

If performance is not a key issue in the case, you can use maybe a bit more convenient but slower query:

```
select id, sum((t ~* 'a')::int) as matches
from example,
lateral unnest(array[text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6]) as t
group by 1;
```

---

You can use the expressions in `WHERE` (query #1) or `HAVING` (query #2) clauses:

```
select *
from example
where
    (text1 ~* 'a')::int+ (text2 ~* 'a')::int+ 
    (text3 ~* 'a')::int+ (text4 ~* 'a')::int+ 
    (text5 ~* 'a')::int+ (text6 ~* 'a')::int > 3;

select e.*
from example e,
lateral unnest(array[text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6]) as t
group by e.id
having sum((t ~* 'a')::int) > 3;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I don't think my question outlined this but im trying to select by the minimum count. So in examples you have provided im not able to do that. Im looking for a query where I can say "where matches > 3" or something like that. Any way to modify your query to reflect this? I attempted but a little stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Like [klin posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091824/939860), but this should be simpler and faster:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM   example e
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE x.t ~* 'keyword') AS ct
   FROM  (VALUES(text1), (text2), (text3), (text4), (text5), (text6)) x(t)
   ) sub ON sub.ct >= 3;  -- your minimum number of columns here
```

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

About `VALUES` in a `LATERAL` join:

- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102702/3684)

About aggregate `FILTER`:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)
- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)