# SQL ecommerce database - getting count of products purchased by only one user

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate

In my rails app I have a typical ecommerce schema inside a Postgres 9.6 database. Here's a simplified version of it:

```
users table
  :name

products table
  :name

shopping_carts table
 :user_id

line_items table
  :price
  :qty
  :product_id
  :shopping_cart_id
```

I've got a working query to return the number of distinct products bought by each user:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct p.*), u.name FROM products p
INNER JOIN line_items l ON p.id = l.product_id
INNER JOIN shopping_carts sc ON l.shopping_cart_id = sc.id
INNER JOIN users u ON sc.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.name
```

But I also want a count of products for each user that only that particular user has purchased. A possible method for this in Ruby (once everything was set up with ActiveRecord) might look something like:

```
def unique_prod(user)
  user.products.select { |p| p.users.length == 1 }.count
end
```

But how to do it in SQL? I think I need to do it using two counts - one for the number of different `user_id`s in a given product's shopping_carts (let's call this count `user_count`), and then a count of products for which `user_count = 1`. I'm having trouble incorporating the multiple `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` statements in working fashion. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it all in one query:

```
SELECT scl.user_id, u.name, ct_dist_prod, ct_dist_prod_exclusive
FROM  (
   SELECT sc.user_id
        , count(DISTINCT l.product_id) AS ct_dist_prod
        , count(DISTINCT l.product_id)
                FILTER (WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                           SELECT 1
                           FROM   shopping_carts sc1
                           JOIN   line_items     l1 ON l1.shopping_cart_id = sc1.id
                           WHERE  l1.product_id = l.product_id 
                           AND    sc1.user_id  <> sc.user_id)) AS ct_dist_prod_exclusive
   FROM   shopping_carts sc
   JOIN   line_items     l ON l.shopping_cart_id = sc.id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) scl
JOIN   users u ON u.id = scl.user_id;
```

I added the `user_id` to the result, because I cannot assume that `name` is defined unique (which would make your original query slightly incorrect).

The aggregate `FILTER` clause requires Postgres 9.4 or later:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

#### How?

Assuming referential integrity enforced by a FK constraint, you do not need to join to the table `products` *at all* for this query.

Neither, at first, to the `users` table. The basic query boils down to:

```
SELECT sc.user_id, count(DISTINCT l.product_id)
FROM   shopping_carts sc
JOIN   line_items     l ON l.shopping_cart_id = sc.id
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Add the 2nd count to this cheaper query, where all rows with products are excluded for which another row with the same product and a different user exists (i.e. bought by a different user, too).

*Then* join to `users` to add the `name`. Cheaper.

---

Computing ***only*** the exclusive count is simpler. Example:

```
SELECT sc.user_id, count(DISTINCT l.product_id) AS ct_dist_prod_exclusive
FROM   shopping_carts  sc
JOIN   line_items      l ON l.shopping_cart_id = sc.id
LEFT   JOIN (
             shopping_carts sc1
       JOIN  line_items     l1 ON l1.shopping_cart_id = sc1.id
       ) ON l1.product_id = l.product_id 
    AND sc1.user_id <> sc.user_id
WHERE  l1.product_id IS NULL
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Note the essential parentheses.

Related:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

***Or*** (in response to your comment):

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) AS ct_dist_prod_exclusive
FROM  (
   SELECT max(user_id) AS user_id, l1.product_id
   FROM   line_items l1
   INNER  JOIN shopping_carts sc1 ON l.shopping_cart_id = sc1.id
   GROUP  BY l1.product_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sc1.user_id) = 1  -- DISTINCT!
   ) p1
GROUP  BY user_id;
```

`HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sc1.user_id) = 1` because

> products purchased by only one user

allows the product to be bought by the same user multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. In your answer it looks like you rely on a user_id foreign key in the line_items table, but I don't have that in my schema.

Comment: @TDB: Right, I adapted the queries accordingly.

Comment: I created this query (based on your original answer) which gives me a different result. Thoughts? (FYI my sql skills are pretty junior) SELECT sc.user_id, count(DISTINCT l.product_id) FROM shopping_carts sc INNER JOIN line_items l on l.shopping_cart_id = sc.id INNER JOIN ( SELECT l1.product_id FROM line_items l1 INNER JOIN shopping_carts sc1 ON l1.shopping_cart_id = sc1.id GROUP BY l1.product_id HAVING COUNT(sc1.user_id) = 1 ) one_user ON one_user.product_id = l.product_id GROUP BY sc.user_id

Comment: @TDB: Good approach. But it would have to be `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sc1.user_id)`, and you can simplify some more. I added another query.