# How to divide two values from the same column but at different rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
postcode | value | uns
AA       | 10    | 51
AB       | 20    | 78
AA       | 20    | 78
AB       | 50    | 51
```

and I want to get a result like:

```
AA | 0.5 
AB | 2.5
```

where the new values are the division for the same postcode between the `value` with `uns = 51` and the `value` with `uns = 78`.
How can I do that with Postgres? I already checked window functions and partitions but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: What if there are more than two lines per postcode?

Comment: window functions partition by sounds very good here - show us your code

Comment: Is `(postcode, uns)` unique? If that's the case, you just need a self-join. EDIT: If that's not the case, please describe what to do with duplicated rows. (I.e. do you want multiple divisions?)

Comment: @fafl every value is unique per same postcode and uns

Comment: @pozs yes I just realised that they are unique (i have more columns on the real table)

Comment: What if you had another row with ("AA", 100, 52)? What would the results be?

Comment: That row doesnt matter in that case, only for that specific uns values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `(postcode, uns)` is unique, all you need is a self-join:

```
select postcode, uns51.value / nullif(uns78.value, 0)
from   t uns51
join   t uns78 using (postcode)
where  uns51.uns = 51
and    uns78.uns = 78
```

If the rows with either `t.uns = 51` or `t.uns = 78` may be missing, you could use a `full join` instead (with possibly `coalesce()` to provide default values for missing rows).

Comment: how can I skip the value if there is a `division by zero`?

Comment: @Randomize [use `nullif()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) -- see the updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

pozs' solution is nice and simple, nothing wrong with it. Just adding two alternatives:

#### 1. Correlated subquery

```sql
SELECT postcode
     , value / (SELECT NULLIF(value, 0) FROM t WHERE postcode = uns51.postcode AND uns = 78)
FROM   t uns51
WHERE  uns = 51;
```

For only one or a few rows.

#### 2. Conditional aggregate

```sql
SELECT postcode
     , min(value) FILTER (WHERE uns = 51)/ NULLIF(min(value) FILTER (WHERE uns = 78), 0) 
FROM   t
GROUP  BY postcode;
```

May be faster when processing most or all of the table.
Can also deal with duplicates per `(postcode, uns)`, use an aggregate function of your choice to pick the right value from each group. For just *one* row in each group, `min()` is just as good as `max()` or `sum()`.
About the aggregate `FILTER`:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

Comment: I found the conditional aggregate approach very useful in a use case where I had a campaign ID instead of a postCode, and an event type instead of a "uns", especially since not all campaigns had all event types.