# Changing data type to float and rounding to 2 decimal digits

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, casting, average

Tables:

```
people(id, name)
job (id, people_id, job_title, salary)
```

> Goal: Display each unique job, the total average salary *(FLOAT and rounded to 2 decimal places)*, the total
>   people and the total salary *(Float and rounded to 2 decimal places)* and order by highest average salary.

So the challenge is to keep the cast type as float while rounding it to 2 decimal places.

I've gotten to where I've rounded it 2 decimal places but it's not float. I've gotten it to where it's float but I can't round it to 2 decimal places.

**My Attempts**:

Attempt 1:

```
SELECT 
  distinct(j.job_title) as job_title,
  to_char(AVG(j.salary)::FLOAT, 'FM999999990.00') as average_salary,
  COUNT(p.id) as total_people,
  CAST (SUM(j.salary) AS FLOAT) as total_salary
  FROM people p
    JOIN job j on p.id = j.people_id
  GROUP BY j.job_title
  ORDER BY total_salary
```

Problem: Still says it's not float

Attempt 2:

```
SELECT 
  distinct(j.job_title) as job_title,
  CAST (AVG(j.salary) AS FLOAT) as average_salary,
  COUNT(p.id) as total_people,
  CAST (SUM(j.salary) AS FLOAT) as total_salary
  FROM people p
    JOIN job j on p.id = j.people_id
  GROUP BY j.job_title
  ORDER BY total_salary
```

Problem: not rounded to 2 decimal places

Attempt 3:

```
SELECT 
  distinct(j.job_title) as job_title,
  ROUND (AVG(CAST(j.salary as FLOAT)), 2)) as average_salary,
  COUNT(p.id),
  ROUND (SUM(CAST(j.salary as FLOAT)), 2)) as total_salary
  FROM people p
    JOIN job j on p.id = j.people_id
  GROUP BY j.job_title
  ORDER BY total_salary
```

I get an error saying I need to add explicit cast types which led me to attempt number 1.

Comment: How about just: `ROUND(AVG(j.salary), 2)::float` ?

Comment: What is the datatype of column `salary`? Is it a `float`, or something else, like `numeric` or `integer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on the actual datatype of column `salary`. The key point is that `round()` in Postgres does not allows `float`s (only `numeric` types are supported).

If you are dealing with a `numeric` datatype, then you can first `round()`, then cast to `float`:

```
round(avg(salary), 2)::float
```

If you are dealing with a `float` column, then you would need to cast the result of the aggregate function before using `round()` on it:

```
round(avg(salary)::numeric, 2)::float
```

Comment: Thank you and  it was a numeric datatype! (to answer your comment above)!

Answer (score 1):

> So the challenge is to keep the cast type as float while rounding it to 2 decimal places.

If you strictly want to avoid casting away from `float`, you could do it like this:

```
test=# 
test=# SELECT float '12.3456'
test-#      , round(float '12.3456' * 100) / 100 AS rounded
 float8  | rounded
---------+----------
 12.3456 |    12.35
```

The point being: [`round()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) taking the number of decimal places as 2nd parameter is based on `numeric` (since floating point numbers are imprecise by nature).
But there is an overloaded variant of `round()` taking a single parameter that rounds to the nearest integer. Multiply by 100 before and divide by 100 after.

Or overcome your aversion against `numeric` and use `round(numeric, int)` [as provided by GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55427074/939860).

#### Query

```
SELECT j.job_title  -- !
     , round(AVG(j.salary) * float '100') / 100 AS average_salary  -- !
     , COUNT(p.id) AS total_people
     , SUM(j.salary)::float AS total_salary  -- short cast syntax
FROM   people p
JOIN   job    j ON p.id = j.people_id
GROUP  BY j.job_title
ORDER  BY total_salary DESC NULLS LAST -- ! "order by highest average salary"
```

- Multiplying by `* float '100'` achieves the cast and the multiplication in one step - because the data type resulting from `avg()` depends on the input, [quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

  > `numeric` for any integer-type argument, `double precision` for a floating-point argument, otherwise the same as the argument data type

  About casting in Postgres:

  - [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)
- `distinct(j.job_title)` is most probably not doing what you may think it does. There is no function `distinct()`. `DISTINCT` is a syntax element - and completely useless here, only  adding cost. See this related case with explanation:

  - [Skip whole row if aggregated value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53675941/skip-whole-row-if-aggregated-value-is-null/53676202#53676202)
- About `NULLS LAST`:

  - [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)