# Why is my CAST not casting to float with 2 decimal places?

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

*This is being tested with PostgreSQL 9.6 - it's a SQL challenge on the CodeWars website.*

https://www.codewars.com/kata/580fb94e12b34dd1c40001f0/train/sql

```
SELECT
  job_title,
  CAST(SUM(salary)/COUNT(salary) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS average_salary,
  COUNT(people_id) AS total_people,
  CAST(SUM(salary) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS total_salary
FROM job
GROUP BY job_title
ORDER BY average_salary DESC;
```

**average_salary 74.4506 --> should be 74.45**

**total_salary 372.253 --> should be 372.25**

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

ROUND(SUM(salary) / COUNT(salary), 2)::FLOAT AS average_salary

Comment: Thank you for answering. CONVERT returns an error, something it does not like about the comma before the CAST inside the CONVERT...


There was an error with the SQL query:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 6:   CONVERT(decimal(10,2), CAST(SUM(salary)/COUNT(salary) AS D...

Comment: my apologize.. should have asked you the database engine you are using.
from the error seems like you are running postgresql
try this link and see whether it works for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426801/changing-data-type-to-float-and-rounding-to-2-decimal-digits

Comment: Thank you. The ROUND function, then ::FLOAT worked!! You're awesome. :-)

Comment: Hi, would appreciate if you can upvote the answer :)

Comment: I checked and voted.. but it says my vote doesn't count.. maybe because I'm too new.. I just joined two days ago.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that your database does integer division and `salary` is an integer.  I would suggest a simple fix:

```
CAST(SUM(salary) * 1.0 / COUNT(salary) AS FLOAT)
```

You don't really need the additional `cast()` to a `flat`, but I left it in.

If you want exactly two decimal places, cast to a `decimal`/`numeric` with the appropriate precision:

```
CAST(SUM(salary) * 1.0 / COUNT(salary) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried that, and weirdly it still gives me the same result. I've been wrecking my brain on this... I'm testing through CodeWars, so wondering if there's something wrong on their side... Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody running into the same issue...

The code was in PostgreSQL 9.6, and below code worked as it should have. Thank you to **Yuyanto** for finding the answer.

*SELECT 

job_title 

,**ROUND(SUM(salary) / COUNT(salary), 2)::FLOAT** AS average_salary 

,COUNT(people_id) AS total_people 

,**ROUND(SUM(salary), 2)::FLOAT** AS total_salary 

FROM job 

GROUP BY job_title 

ORDER BY average_salary DESC;* <br