# Get max value from a window of rows as new column for all rows

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

```
| col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
|-------|-------|-------|
| 67458 | ADM   | 1008  |
| 67458 | ADM   | 1009  |
| 67458 | SKI   | 1009  |
| 67458 | LIS   | 1010  |
| 67458 | TOU   | 1121  |
```

How to get max value of `col3` when `col2='ADM'` and use that as the value for rest of the records?

Expected Result:

```
| col 1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4 |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 67458 | ADM   | 1008  | 1009  |
| 67458 | ADM   | 1009  | 1009  |
| 67458 | SKI   | 1009  | 1009  |
| 67458 | LIS   | 1010  | 1009  |
| 67458 | TOU   | 1121  | 1009  |
```

I know how to do this with sub-selects and all. `col4` will be a pseudo-column to be used downstream for JOINs and stuff.

I have tried the following but it populates *1121* instead of *1009*:

```
MAX(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 (CASE WHEN col2='ADM' THEN col2 END) ORDER BY col1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*, max(CASE WHEN col2 = 'ADM' THEN col3 END) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) AS col4
FROM   tbl t;
```

The aggregate `FILTER` clause was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.4 and would be nice for this. But Redshift is not Postgres, and most of the later additions in Postgres are unsupported there. Compare:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select t.*,
       (select max(t1.col3) from table t1 where t1.col1 = t.col1 and t1.col2 = 'ADM') as col4
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(col3) filter (where col2 = 'ADM') over (partition by col1) as col4
from t;
```

In Redshift, you probably have to use `case`:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when col2 = 'ADM' then col3 end) over (partition by col1) as col4
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Does this work in Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query in your `SELECT` to get that value.

This suq-query can be stored in a variable if you mind executing it again and again and cross joining it.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  "col 1" INTEGER,
  "col 2" VARCHAR(3),
  "col 3" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test
  ("col 1", "col 2", "col 3")
VALUES
  ('67458', 'ADM', '1008'),
  ('67458', 'ADM', '1009'),
  ('67458', 'SKI', '1009'),
  ('67458', 'LIS', '1010'),
  ('67458', 'TOU', '1121');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT MAX("col 3") AS "col 4" INTO col4 FROM test t2 WHERE t2."col 2" = 'ADM';
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT "col 1",
       "col 2",
       "col 3",
       "col 4"
FROM test
CROSS JOIN
col4;
```

**Output**

```
| col 1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4 |
| ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| 67458 | ADM   | 1008  | 1009  |
| 67458 | ADM   | 1009  | 1009  |
| 67458 | SKI   | 1009  | 1009  |
| 67458 | LIS   | 1010  | 1009  |
| 67458 | TOU   | 1121  | 1009  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/krGAErhLKUYpPqa8VbU2aY/4)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I had this in my mind, but the test table is really huge. Isn't it going to be a bad code if use test to calculate on pseudo column

Comment: You can pre-calculate the value and store it in a variable