# How to get the latest non-negative value in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I've the following dataset.

| date | orig | dest | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11-4 | S8 | B9 | -42 |
| 10-30 | S8 | B9 | -2999 |
| 10-15 | S8 | B9 | 959 |
| 10-14 | S8 | B9 | 480 |
| 10-13 | S8 | B9 | 0 |
| 10-9 | S8 | B9 | 503 |

How do I convert it into something like this?

| date | orig | dest | value | new value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11-4 | S8 | B9 | -42 | 959 |
| 10-30 | S8 | B9 | -2999 | 959 |
| 10-15 | S8 | B9 | 959 | 959 |
| 10-14 | S8 | B9 | 480 | 480 |
| 10-13 | S8 | B9 | 0 | 503 |
| 10-9 | S8 | B9 | 503 | 503 |

This is what I've using and is incorrect:

```
CASE WHEN value <= 0
     THEN last_value(value) over (PARTITION BY orig, dest ORDER BY date DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
     ELSE value 
END as new_value
```

The goal is here to not to replace the <=0 values with the maximum recent value but rather with the latest non-negative recent value.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it in Redshift:

```sql
SELECT date, orig, dest, value
     , max(value) OVER (PARTITION BY orig, dest, grp) AS new_value
FROM  (
   SELECT date, orig, dest, value
        , count(value > 0 OR NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY orig, dest ORDER BY date) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
```

Explanation:

- [Retrieve last known value for each column of a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246242/retrieve-last-known-value-for-each-column-of-a-row/20253371#20253371)

About `count(expression OR NULL)`, see:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)

Unfortunately, Redshift did not keep up with improvements to Postgres and lacks the aggregate `FILTER` clause (since Postgres 9.4!), which would be faster and more elegant:

```sql
SELECT date, orig, dest, value
     , max(value) OVER (PARTITION BY orig, dest, grp) AS new_value
FROM  (
   SELECT date, orig, dest, value
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE value > 0) OVER (PARTITION BY orig, dest ORDER BY date) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
```

See:

- [Get max value from a window of rows as new column for all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420524/get-max-value-from-a-window-of-rows-as-new-column-for-all-rows/55420899#55420899)
- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)