# How to COALESCE different values in an UPDATE depending on whether a subquery exists or returns null?

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, floating-point, divide-by-zero

I have two tables, `posts` and `stars`. When the `rank` (a post column, `integer type`) of a post entry (row) is changed, I want to update the `priority` (a post column, double precision type) value. The `priority` calculation needs to take into account a subquery from another table called `stars` (for `star_count` and `total_stars` as floats) which is dependent on whether an `action` (a `stars` column, `boolean type`) exists.

I thought that the problem might be related to the `NULLIF statement` in my `COALESCE` section improperly checking if the subquery exists (`is null`), but  am not sure how else I could solve this.

```
UPDATE posts
SET priority = (
    COALESCE(
        NULLIF (subquery.star_count/CAST(subquery.total_stars AS FLOAT), ''),
        0.0
    ) + posts.rank)
FROM (
    SELECT sum(CASE action WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS star_count, count(*) AS total_stars
    FROM stars
    WHERE post_id = $1
    ) AS subquery
WHERE posts.id = $1
```

Expectation:

- if "action" exists (as either 1 OR 0), then calculate `priority` = (`star_count` / `total_stars`) + `posts.rank`
- else if "action" doesn't exist, calculate `priority` = `0.0` + `posts.rank`

Unfortunately, anytime I trigger a change of the `rank` value of a posts entry with no existing "action", I receive the error:

> ```
> ERROR 22P02 (invalid_text_representation) invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
> ```

Should I instead be trying something with `CASE` and `EXISTS`?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: after trying @Erwin Brandstetter's solution, the calculation of priority doesn't yield the expected result.

When testing the scenario where `action` does not exist yet (intentionally):

```
Attempt  |  Rank  | Priority (actual) | Priority (expected) | Action
1        |  0     |    null           | 0                   | null
2        |  1     |    0              | 1                   | null
3        |  0     |    1              | 0                   | null
4        |  1     |    0              | 1                   | null
5        |  2     |    1              | 2                   | null
6        |  3     |    2              | 3                   | null
7        |  4     |    3              | 4                   | null
8        |  5     |    4              | 5                   | null
9        |  1     |    5              | 1                   | null
10       |  2     |    1              | 2                   | null
11       |  4     |    2              | 4                   | null
```

Priority does seem to get calculated after each update, but why does it not follow the else statement correctly?

Answer (score 0):

That should fix the error, avoid *division by zero* properly, and perform better:

```
UPDATE posts p
SET    priority =
         CASE WHEN sub.star_count > 0  -- both > 0, follows logically
            THEN p.rank + sub.star_count / sub.total_stars::float
            ELSE p.rank
         END
FROM  (
    SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE action) AS star_count
         , count(*)::float AS total_stars
    FROM   stars
    WHERE  post_id = $1
    ) sub
WHERE  p.id = $1;
```

Assuming `action`is a boolean type.

The problem was in this expression:

```
NULLIF (subquery.star_count/CAST(subquery.total_stars AS FLOAT), '')
```

The empty string (`''`) has no representation in `double precision` (`float`). Hence the error.

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.It no longer errors out and certainly performs faster, but the results don't appear reflect expected outcome. See updated post.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about the aggregate `FILTER` clause. Does your suggestion assign binary vaules and sum up the boolean `action` as intended from my approach?

Comment: It would be much easier to tell with actual `CREATE TABLE` statements. Or a fiddle, even. Random example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=14cad1559687ac0e0bc8853e377814bb