# Counting null values between dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to calculate the number of null values between dates.

My table looks like this:

```
transaction_date    transaction_sale
10/1/2018           NULL
11/1/2018           33
12/1/2018           NULL
1/1/2019            NULL
2/1/2019            NULL
3/1/2019            2
4/1/2019            NULL
5/1/2019            NULL
6/1/2019            10
```

I'm looking to get the following output:

```
transaction_date    transaction_sale   count
10/1/2018           NULL               NULL
11/1/2018           33                 1
12/1/2018           NULL               NULL
1/1/2019            NULL               NULL
2/1/2019            NULL               NULL
3/1/2019            2                  3
4/1/2019            NULL               NULL
5/1/2019            NULL               NULL
6/1/2019            10                 2
```

Comment: sounds like a `lag` function roll down calculation

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any assumptions about consecutive dates, etc.

```
with data as (
    select transaction_date, transaction_sale,
        count(transaction_sale)
            over (order by transaction_date desc) as grp
    from T /* replace with your table */
)
select transaction_date, transaction_sale,
    case when transaction_sale is null then null else
        count(case when transaction_sale is null then 1 end)
            over (partition by grp) end as "count"
from data
order by transaction_date;
```

See a demo here. Although the demo is SQL Server it should work identically on your platform: https://rextester.com/GVR65084

Also see for PostgreSQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/07c85f/1

Comment: @jarlh It will work on PostgreSQL as well. SQLFiddle was down at the time.

Answer (score 1):

`count(`***`expression`***`)` does not count NULL values, be it as aggregate function or as window function. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE)

> number of input rows for which the value of **expression** is not null

This is the key element for a **simple and fast** query.

Assuming `transaction_date` is `UNIQUE` like your example suggests, or you'll have to define how to break ties between duplicate values. (An actual table definition would clarify.)

```
SELECT transaction_date, transaction_sale
     , CASE WHEN transaction_sale IS NOT NULL
            THEN count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) - 1
       END AS count 
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , count(transaction_sale) OVER (ORDER BY transaction_date DESC) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
ORDER  BY transaction_date;
```

Form groups in the subquery. Since every nonnull value starts a new group according to your definition, just count actual values in descending order in a window function to effectively assign a group number to every row. The rest is trivial.

In the outer `SELECT`, count the rows per group and display where `transaction_sale IS NOT NULL`. Fix off-by-1. Voilá.

Related:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

**Alternatively**, count with `FILTER (WHERE transaction_sale IS NULL)` - useful for related cases where we cannot simply subtract *1*:

```
SELECT transaction_date, transaction_sale
     , CASE WHEN transaction_sale IS NOT NULL
            THEN count(*) FILTER (WHERE transaction_sale IS NULL)
                          OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
       END AS count 
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , count(transaction_sale) OVER (ORDER BY transaction_date DESC) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
ORDER  BY transaction_date;
```

About the `FILTER` clause:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c9bc5eae0345093528d958011385a572)*

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are consecutive, you can use the following to get the previous date:

```
select t.*,
       max(transaction_date) filter where (transaction_sale is not null) over (order by transaction_date order by transaction date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
from t;
```

If the difference is less than 12, you can use `age()` and `extract()`:

```
select t.*,
       extract(month from
               age(max(transaction_date) filter where (transaction_sale is notnull)
                       over (order by transaction_date order by transaction date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                            ), transaction_date
                   )
               ) as diff
```

Answer (score 0):

If transaction date is a date field you can simply use:

```
select count(*) from Counter where transaction_date > date_lower and transaction_date < date_higher and tx_sale is null;
```