# How to remove and carry forward month prior when running balance decreases?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the following data:

| client_id | balance_month | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | $7000 |
| 100000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | $7000 |
| 100000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $6000 |
| 100000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $3000 |
| 100000000 | May 1,2021 12:00 AM | $20000 |
| 100000000 | April 1,2021 12:00 AM | $1000 |
| 100000000 | March 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |
| 200000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | $7000 |
| 200000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | $7000 |
| 200000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $8000 |
| 200000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $9000 |
| 200000000 | May 1,2021 12:00 AM | $1000 |
| 200000000 | April 1,2021 12:00 AM | $1000 |
| 200000000 | March 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |

I want to overwrite any month where a balance decreased with the most recent month that whose balance did not decrease. (Assume that the balances started March 2021, but want to automate for much longer)

| client_id | balance_month | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | $7000 |
| 100000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | $7000 |
| 100000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $6000 |
| 100000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $3000 |
| 100000000 | May 1,2021 12:00 AM | $1000 |
| 100000000 | April 1,2021 12:00 AM | $1000 |
| 100000000 | March 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |
| 200000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | $7000 |
| 200000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | $1000 |
| 200000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $1000 |
| 200000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $1000 |
| 200000000 | May 1,2021 12:00 AM | $1000 |
| 200000000 | April 1,2021 12:00 AM | $1000 |
| 200000000 | March 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |

Comment: How is this different from your most recent question?

Comment: Instead of $0'ing out months prior when there is a decrease it gets the last value where there wasn't a month-to-month decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all columns `NOT NULL`, or you have to do more.

```sql
SELECT client_id, balance_month
     , COALESCE(balance_null, first_value(balance_null) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id, balance_grp ORDER BY balance_month)) AS new_balance
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , count(balance_null) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY balance_month) AS balance_grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT client_id, balance_month
           , CASE WHEN lead(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY balance_month) < balance THEN NULL ELSE balance END AS balance_null
      FROM   tbl
      ORDER  BY client_id, balance_month
      ) sub1
   ) sub2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e73369ffa88c84bdf18902d3b5e15875)*

In subquery `sub1`, set `balance` to NULL if `balance` of the following row is smaller (your replace condition).

In subquery `sub2`, form groups for consecutive NULL values, including the leading nonnull value (`balance_grp`) using `count(balance_null)`, because that omits NULL values from the count so that every NULL value falls into a group with the last valid (nonnull) value.

In the outer `SELECT`, replace NULL values with the leading nonnull value from each group. Voilá.

**If** `balance` can be assumed to be growing steadily (or at least stagnating) in all non-offending rows, we can use a simpler query:

```sql
SELECT client_id, balance_month
     , COALESCE(balance_null, max(balance_null) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY balance_month))
FROM  (
   SELECT client_id, balance_month
        , CASE WHEN lead(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY balance_month) < balance THEN NULL ELSE balance END AS balance_null
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY client_id, balance_month
   ) sub1;
```

Related:

- [Counting null values between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174638/counting-null-values-between-dates/58175613#58175613)
- [Form groups of consecutive rows with same value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166397/3684)
- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)