# Combining two or more different SELECT queries to same table with different conditions in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express

I need to retrieve two different results from the same table, and combine them into a single result set. I'm using aggregate functions to generate reports on some data, and each column has different "where" conditions.

```
select sum(price) 
as lucro_esperado 
from tasks 
where extract(month from enddate) = 12 
AND extract(year from enddate) = 2019
```

and

```
select count(*) 
as tarefas_abertas 
from tasks 
where extract(month from date_added) = 12 
AND extract(year from date_added) = 2019
```

Since all I'm interested in this case are the aggregate functions results, I'm unable to use Join statements (as there's no **ON** condition), and Union ones will complain about different data types, as it's trying to wrongfully merge both aggregate results into a single column. Any other way I can achieve this, without having to query the database twice from my Node.js endpoint, and combining them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write this as one query:

```
select sum(price) as lucro_esperado, count(*) as tarefas_abertas
from tasks
where extract(month from enddate) = 12 and
      extract(year from enddate) = 2019
```

I would advise you to change the `where` clause to:

```
where enddate >= '2019-12-01' and
      enddate < '2020-01-01'
```

This allows the database to use an index on `enddate` (if available).  Also, removing the function calls on the column helps the optimizer.

EDIT:

I see, the two date parameters are different.  Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when enddate >= '2019-12-01' and enddate < '2020-01-01' then price end) as lucro_esperado,
       sum(case when date_added >= '2019-12-01' and date_added < '2020-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as tarefas_abertas
from tasks;
```

Comment: I cannot since I need sum(price) to use the enddate parameter (for payments that are due this month) and count(*) to use the date_added parameter (for tasks that were added this month), since these two collumns are not necessarily always within the same month (eg a task added on 11/28, that's due 12/15)

Comment: @RafaelOliveira . . . I see.  Those are *different* dates.  Just use conditional aggregation.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea of what you did there sir, but works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use the aggregate **`FILTER`** clause for conditional aggregation. And keep `count(*)` like you had it. That's shorter and faster:

```
SELECT sum(price) FILTER (WHERE enddate    >= '2019-12-01' AND enddate    < '2020-01-01') AS lucro_esperado
     , count(*)   FILTER (WHERE date_added >= '2019-12-01' AND date_added < '2020-01-01') AS tarefas_abertas
FROM   tasks;
```

Related:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

And it's typically faster, yet, if you repeat the superset of conditions in an outer `WHERE` clause to eliminate rows early and put indexes to good use:

```
SELECT sum(price) FILTER (WHERE enddate    >= '2019-12-01' AND enddate    < '2020-01-01') AS lucro_esperado
     , count(*)   FILTER (WHERE date_added >= '2019-12-01' AND date_added < '2020-01-01') AS tarefas_abertas
FROM   tasks
WHERE  enddate    >= '2019-12-01' AND enddate    < '2020-01-01'
OR     date_added >= '2019-12-01' AND date_added < '2020-01-01';
```

Depending on the actual data type of `enddate` and `date_added`, you may want to adjust the input to remove dependency on the current time zone setting of your session. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)