# Complex nested aggregations to get order totals

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a system to track orders and related expenditures.  This is a Rails app running on PostgreSQL.  99% of my app gets by with plain old Rails Active Record call etc.  This one is ugly.

The `expenditures` table look like this:

```
+----+----------+-----------+------------------------+
| id | category | parent_id | note                   |
+----+----------+-----------+------------------------+
| 1  | order    | nil       | order with no invoices |
+----+----------+-----------+------------------------+
| 2  | order    | nil       | order with invoices    |
+----+----------+-----------+------------------------+
| 3  | invoice  | 2         | invoice for order 2    |
+----+----------+-----------+------------------------+
| 4  | invoice  | 2         | invoice for order 2    |
+----+----------+-----------+------------------------+
```

Each `expenditure` has many `expenditure_items` and can the orders can be parents to the invoices.  That table looks like this:

```
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| id | expenditure_id | cbs_item_id | total | note    |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 1  | 1              | 1           | 5     | Fuit    |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 2  | 1              | 2           | 15    | Veggies |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 3  | 2              | 1           | 123   | Fuit    |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 4  | 2              | 2           | 456   | Veggies |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 5  | 3              | 1           | 34    | Fuit    |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 6  | 3              | 2           | 76    | Veggies |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 7  | 4              | 1           | 26    | Fuit    |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 8  | 4              | 2           | 98    | Veggies |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------+---------+
```

I need to track a few things:

- amounts left to be invoiced on orders (thats easy)
- above but rolled up for each `cbs_item_id` (this is the ugly part)

The cbs_item_id is basically an accounting code to categorize the money spent etc.  I have visualized what my end result would look like:

```
+-------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------+
| cbs_item_id | expenditure_id | order_total | invoice_total             | remaining |
+-------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------+
| 1           | 1              | 5           | 0                         | 5         |
+-------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------+
| 1           | 2              | 123         | 60                        | 63        |
+-------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|             |                |             | Rollup for cbs_item_id: 1 | 68        |
+-------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------+
| 2           | 1              | 15          | 0                         | 15        |
+-------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------+
| 2           | 2              | 456         | 174                       | 282       |
+-------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|             |                |             | Rollup for cbs_item_id: 2 | 297       |
+-------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------+
```

`order_total` is the sum of `total` for all the expenditure_items of the given order ( category = 'order').  `invoice_total` is the sum of total for all the expenditure_items with parent_id = expenditures.id.  Remaining is calculated as the difference (but not greater than 0).  In real terms the idea here is you place and order for $1000 and $750 of invoices come in.  I need to calculate that $250 left on the order (remaining) - broken down into each category (`cbs_item_id`).  Then I need the roll-up of all the remaining values grouped by the `cbs_item_id`.

So for each `cbs_item_id` I need group by each order, find the total for the order, find the total invoiced against the order then subtract the two (also can't be negative).  It has to be on a per order basis - the overall aggregate difference will not return the expected results.

In the end looking for a result something like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| cbs_item_id | remaining |
+-------------+-----------+
| 1           | 68        |
+-------------+-----------+
| 2           | 297       |
+-------------+-----------+
```

I am guessing this might be a combination of GROUP BY and perhaps a sub query or even CTE (voodoo to me). My SQL skills are not that great and this is WAY above my pay grade.

Here is a fiddle for the data above:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2fe3a

Alternate fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e9528042874206477efbe0f0e86326fb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query produces the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT cbs_item_id, sum(order_total - invoice_total) AS remaining
FROM  (
   SELECT cbs_item_id
        , COALESCE(e.parent_id, e.id) AS expenditure_id -- ①
        , COALESCE(sum(total) FILTER (WHERE e.category = 'order'  ), 0) AS order_total -- ②
        , COALESCE(sum(total) FILTER (WHERE e.category = 'invoice'), 0) AS invoice_total
   FROM   expenditures      e
   JOIN   expenditure_items i ON i.expenditure_id = e.id
   GROUP  BY 1, 2 -- ③
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6008be14f43c23068b7311dfc92c4f8a)*

① Note how I assume a saner table definition with `expenditures.parent_id` being `integer`, and true `NULL` instead of the string 'nil'. This allows the simple use of [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

② About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

③ Using short syntax with [ordinal numbers of an `SELECT` list items](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY). Example:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

> can I get the total of all the remaining for all rows or do I need to wrap that into another sub select?

There is a very concise option with [`GROUPING SETS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS):

```
...
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ((1), ())  -- that's all :)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=197a63191d678553e3e725b15f9ddb18)*

Related:

- [Converting rows to columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/134917/3684)

Comment: Yes - its a true NULL.  This helps - I somehow I actually can follow the logic here .  Going to try this in my actual app - this seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Side question - now that I see your answer I should have perhaps re-framed my question.  I have a query for the cbs_items i.e. {id = 1, name = 'fruit'}, {id=2, name = 'veggies'} etc.  In the end interface I want to list these (including the cbs_items with no expenditures etc.).

Comment: @DanTappin: Just start a new question. This time, lead with actual minimal table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement like in the fiddle) and your version of Postgres. You can always link to this one for context, and drop a comment here to link back.

Comment: I think I actually figured it out - did the first FROM from the cbs_items then double left joins.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e521b78ff8e8d4e7d9bba0eee37d5dd5  I am going to try and do this the 'Rails' way also to make it easier to integrate into my app. 

Comment: Take a first stab at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706844/complex-nested-aggregations-to-get-order-totals-part-2

Comment: The only note here is I had to add a CASE to the main sum to filter out any negative numbers in the subtraction.

Comment: This works great - can I get the total of all the remaining for all rows or do I need to wrap that into another sub select?

Comment: @DanTappin: `GROUPING SETS`. I added another answer.