# What does filter mean?

Tags: postgresql

```
select driverid, count(*) 
from f1db.results
    where position is  null
group by driverid order by driverid
```

My thought: first find out all the records that position is null then do the aggregate function.

```
select driverid, count(*) filter (where position is null) as outs
   from f1db.results 
group by driverid order by driverid
```

First time, I meet with filter clause, not sure what does it mean?
Two code block results are different.
Already googled, seems don't have many tutorials about the FILTER. Kindly share some links.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27141193/939860, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684

Answer (score 2):

A more helpful term to search for is `aggregate filters`, since `FILTER (WHERE)` is only used with aggregates.

Filter clauses are an additional filter that is applied only to that aggregate and nowhere else. That means it doesn't affect the rest of the columns!

You can use it to get a subset of the data, like for example, to get the percentage of cats in a pet shop:

```sql
SELECT shop_id,
       CAST(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE species = 'cat')
            AS DOUBLE PRECISION) / COUNT(*) as "percentage"
FROM animals
GROUP BY shop_id
```

For more information, see [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

Answer (score 1):

`FILTER` ehm... filters the records which should be aggregated - in your case, your aggregation counts all `position`s that are `NULL`.

E.g. you have 10 records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

would return 10.

If 2 of the records have `position = NULL`

than

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE position IS NULL)
```

would return 2.

What you want to achieve is to count all non-`NULL` records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE position IS NOT NULL)
```

In the example, it returns 8.

Comment: So In this scenario, It looks like the same as HAVING. Since HAVING also is first do aggregate function then do the filter function.

Comment: HAVING counts all values, no matter how they look. It's not possible to count only the NULL values with HAVING without applying a WHERE clause. But the WHERE clause would remove the records from the result, whereas FILTER just removes them from the aggregate. FILTER allows a fine adjustment for the input of each aggregate. More: When yku have more aggregates, say COUNT and SUM, you can apply different FILTERs on them: COUNT without NULL and SUM only values over ten (`FILTER (WHERE position > 10)`)