# Get total count and filtered count from single subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-filter

`product` table

| product_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | t-shirt |
| 2 | shirt |

`users` table

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sphinx |

`favorite` table with a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(user_id, product_id)`:

| user_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

What is best way to query this table for `user_id = 1`

`favorite_count`: how many users added this product in favorite?
`isfavorite`: did user with `user_id = 1` add this product as favorite?

Expected result:

| product_id | product_name | isfavorite | favorite_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t-shirt | false | 0 |
| 2 | shirt | true | 1 |

Comment: What do "isfavorite" and "favorite_count" mean? Can one user have more than one favorite products?

Comment: it is mean that product is in user('user_id' = 1) favorites  and yes user can have more than one favorite product

Comment: there is button in product card ,it is red if user added this product in favorites

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite the question ot make it clear. Please fix if I got anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, it's cheapest to aggregate rows in the n-table (`favorite` in this case) before the join:

```sql
SELECT p.*
     , COALESCE(f.is_favorite, false) AS is_favorite
     , COALESCE(f.favorite_count, 0)  AS favorite_count
FROM   product p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT product_id
        , count(*) AS favorite_count            -- total count
        , bool_or(true) FILTER (WHERE user_id = 1) AS is_favorite  -- for given user
   FROM   favorite
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) f USING (product_id);
```

We don't need the `users` table for the query.

`LEFT JOIN` keeps all products in the result, while only adding counts for products that have favorite entries.

About the `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Since not every product has entries in table `favorite`, use [`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) in the outer query to replace resulting NULL values with your defaults.