# Postgres JSONB select json objects as columns

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, crosstab

The table has an id and step_data columns.

```
id | step_data
--------------
a1 | {...}
a2 | {...}
a3 | {...}
```

Where step_data is nested structure as follows, where the actual keys of the metadata can be in of the `events` objects.

```json
{
  "events": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2021-04-07T17:46:13.739Z",
      "meta": [
        {
          "key": "length",
          "value": "0.898"
        },
        {
          "key": "height",
          "value": "607023104"
        },
        {
          "key": "weight",
          "value": "33509376"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "2021-04-07T17:46:13.781Z",
      "meta": [
        {
          "key": "color",
          "value": "0.007"
        },
        {
          "key": "count",
          "value": "641511424"
        },
        {
          "key": "age",
          "value": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can extract one field like `length` pretty easily.

```sql
select cast(metadata ->> 'value' as double precision) as length,
       id
from (
         select jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(step_data #> '{events}') #> '{meta}') metadata,
                id
         from table
     ) as parsed_keys
where metadata @> '{
  "key": "length"
}'::jsonb
```

| id | length |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 0.898 |
| a2 | 0.800 |

But what I really need is to extract the metadata as columns from a couple of known keys, like `length` and `color`. Not sure how to get another column efficiently once I split the array with `jsonb_array_elements()`.

Is there an efficient way to do this without having to call `jsonb_array_elements()` again and do a join on every single one? For example such that the result set looks like this.

| id | length | color | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 0.898 | 0.007 | 33509376 |
| a2 | 0.800 | 1.000 | 15812391 |

Using Postgres 11.7.

Comment: What if the keys in the `meta` array elements aren't unique? E.g. you have `color` in multiple of them? Something like this: https://pastebin.com/m5Lbn3c6

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Using PG 11.7 btw. And query can assume there is only one key overall per JSON structure. If there are more than one then having query fail fast would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This query is an option:

```
SELECT id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN metadata->>'key' = 'length' THEN  metadata->>'value' END) AS length,
  MAX(CASE WHEN metadata->>'key' = 'color' THEN  metadata->>'value' END) AS color,
  MAX(CASE WHEN metadata->>'key' = 'weight' THEN  metadata->>'value' END) AS weight

FROM (SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(step_data #> '{events}') #> '{meta}') as metadata 
      FROM table t) AS aux
   
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

With Postgres 11, I can only think of unnesting both levels, then aggregating back into a key/value pair from which you can extract the desired keys:

```
select t.id, 
       (x.att ->> 'length')::numeric as length,
       (x.att ->> 'color')::numeric as color,
       (x.att ->> 'weight')::numeric as weight
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
     select jsonb_object_agg(m.item ->> 'key', m.item -> 'value') as att
     from jsonb_array_elements(t.step_data -> 'events') as e(event)
      cross join jsonb_array_elements(e.event -> 'meta') as m(item)
     where m.item ->> 'key' in ('color', 'length', 'weight')
  ) x
;
```

---

With Postgres 12 you could write it a bit simpler:

```
select t.id, 
       jsonb_path_query_first(t.step_data, '$.events[*].meta[*] ? (@.key == "length").value') #>> '{}' as length,
       jsonb_path_query_first(t.step_data, '$.events[*].meta[*] ? (@.key == "color").value') #>> '{}' as color,
       jsonb_path_query_first(t.step_data, '$.events[*].meta[*] ? (@.key == "weight").value') #>> '{}' as weight
from the_table t
;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `crosstab()`

For any Postgres version.

You could feed the result into the `crosstab()` function to pivot the result. You need the additional module `tablefunc` installed. If you are unfamiliar, read basic instructions here first:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT id, metadata->>'key', metadata ->>'value'
   FROM  (SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(step_data -> 'events') -> 'meta') metadata FROM tbl) AS parsed_keys
   ORDER  BY 1
   $$
 , $$VALUES ('length'), ('color'), ('weight')$$
   ) AS ct (id text, length float, color float, weight float);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d84c648191594b4c4472708c8b66a94)* (demonstrating all)

Should deliver best performance, especially for many columns.

Note how we need no explicit cast to `double precision` (`float`). `crosstab()` processes `text` input anyway, the result is coerced to the types given in the column definition list.

If one of the keys should appear multiple times, the *last* row wins. (No error is raised, like you would seem to prefer.) You can add a deterministic sort order to the query in $1 to sort the preferred row last. Example: to get the lowest value per key:

```
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3 DESC
```

#### Conditional aggregates with `FILTER` clause

For Postgres 9.4 or newer.

See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

```sql
SELECT id
     , min(val) FILTER (WHERE key = 'length') AS length
     , min(val) FILTER (WHERE key = 'color') AS color
     , min(val) FILTER (WHERE key = 'weight') AS weight
FROM (
   SELECT id, metadata->>'key' AS key, (metadata ->>'value')::float AS val
   FROM  (SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(step_data -> 'events') -> 'meta') metadata FROM tbl) AS parsed_keys
   ) sub
GROUP  BY id;
```

In Postgres 12 or later I would compare performance with [`jsonb_path_query_first()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE). [a_horse provided a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67273823/939860).

Comment: Thanks for putting together that dbfiddle.