# Sum of alias columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-filter

I have a query aggregating three result columns:

`pending_with_documents`
`pending_without_documents`
`inprocessing`

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
                           WHEN status_code IN ('ACK', 'INT') THEN
                               CASE
                                   WHEN ack_no IN
                                        (SELECT ack_no FROM bescom_appl_upload_doc) THEN ack_no END
    END))        AS pending_with_documents,
       COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
                           WHEN status_code IN ('ACK', 'INT') THEN
                               CASE
                                   WHEN ack_no NOT IN
                                        (SELECT ack_no FROM bescom_appl_upload_doc) THEN ack_no END
           END)) AS pending_without_documents,
       COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN status_code NOT IN ('ACK', 'INT', 'APR', 'REJ', 'SBK', 'OBJ') THEN
                     ack_no
           END)  AS Inprocessing
FROM application_ht_install
WHERE service_code IN (36);
```

Now I need a **fourth column `total`** summing up these three. So I tried:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
                           WHEN status_code IN ('ACK', 'INT') THEN
                               CASE
                                   WHEN ack_no IN
                                        (SELECT ack_no FROM bescom_appl_upload_doc) THEN ack_no END
    END))                             AS pending_with_documents,
       COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
                           WHEN status_code IN ('ACK', 'INT') THEN
                               CASE
                                   WHEN ack_no NOT IN
                                        (SELECT ack_no FROM bescom_appl_upload_doc) THEN ack_no END
           END))                      AS pending_without_documents,
       COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN status_code NOT IN ('ACK', 'INT', 'APR', 'REJ', 'SBK', 'OBJ')
                     THEN ack_no END) AS Inprocessing
    SUM((COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN status_code IN ('ACK','INT') THEN
    CASE WHEN ack_no IN
    (SELECT ack_no FROM bescom_appl_upload_doc) THEN ack_no END
    END)) AS pending_with_documents )+ ( COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN status_code  IN ('ACK','INT') THEN
    CASE WHEN ack_no NOT IN
    (SELECT ack_no FROM bescom_appl_upload_doc) THEN ack_no END
    END)) AS pending_without_documents)+ ( COUNT(CASE WHEN status_code NOT IN('ACK','INT','APR','REJ','SBK','OBJ') THEN
    ack_no
    END) AS Inprocessing))
FROM application_ht_install
WHERE service_code IN (36);
```

But I'm getting an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "sum"
> LINE 13: sum((count(distinct(case when status_code in ('ACK','INT') t...
>               ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 473
> ```

How to add up these three derived columns?

Comment: Write an outer query where your query is a subquery in the `FROM` list, and add the columns in thatbouter query?

Comment: Start with actual, precise table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) - it matters! (If any NULL values are involved, `NOT IN` may not be doing what you think it's doing ...) And always your Postgres version.

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors in your statement. You were aliasing things that didn't need aliasing.
Here's the code with the syntax errors corrected. Note: One column had no alias so I called it "do_not_know_name" because I cannot tell what you meant.

```
select 
count(distinct(case when status_code in ('ACK','INT') then 
case when ack_no in
(select ack_no from bescom_appl_upload_doc) then ack_no end 
end)) as pending_with_documents ,
count(distinct(case when status_code  in ('ACK','INT') then 
case when ack_no not in
(select ack_no from bescom_appl_upload_doc) then ack_no end 
end)) as pending_without_documents ,
count(case when status_code not in('ACK','INT','APR','REJ','SBK','OBJ') 
then ack_no end) as Inprocessing,
sum((count(distinct(case when status_code in ('ACK','INT') then 
case when ack_no in
(select ack_no from bescom_appl_upload_doc) then ack_no end 
end))  )+ ( count(distinct(case when status_code  in ('ACK','INT') then 
case when ack_no not in
(select ack_no from bescom_appl_upload_doc) then ack_no end 
end)) )+ ( count(case when status_code not in('ACK','INT','APR','REJ','SBK','OBJ') then 
ack_no
end) )) as do_not_know_name
from application_ht_install where service_code in (36)
```

Comment: I see a couple of nested aggregate calls here in his query, I think Nested aggregate calls are not allowed. `sum((count(distinct(case` and two of `))  )+ ( count(distinct`. Isn't it right?

Comment: @dinidu: Not 100% sure, I don't have the DDL for the tables with data in them, but at least we got past the syntax errors. Was hoping that OP would try this and see if it works or not, or come back with more feedback-- without knowing the data, it's difficult to suggest an alternative without more information. Figured this was the easiest way to get more.

Comment: Also, you can technical have nested aggregates but only if the resolve to a single value prior to being ran... aka: select sum((select avg(some_column) from some_other_source)) from some_table

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can either repeat your lengthy expressions, or put everything in a subquery and sum in an outer `SELECT`. I suggest the later:

```sql
SELECT pending_with_documents
     , pending - pending_with_documents AS pending_without_documents
     , inprocessing
     , pending + inprocessing AS total
FROM  (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT a.ack_no) FILTER (WHERE status_code IN ('ACK', 'INT'))              AS pending
        , count(DISTINCT b.ack_no) FILTER (WHERE status_code IN ('ACK', 'INT'))              AS pending_with_documents
        , count(ack_no) FILTER (WHERE status_code <> ALL ('{ACK, INT, APR, REJ, SBK, OBJ}')) AS inprocessing
   FROM   application_ht_install a
   LEFT   JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ack_no FROM bescom_appl_upload_doc) b USING (ack_no)
   WHERE  service_code = 36
   ) sub;
```

This ***might*** do what you are after. Depends on actual table definitions. If `ack_no` in either table or `status_code` can be `NULL`, you probably need to do more. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Also, the `LEFT JOIN` to a subquery may or may not be more efficient, depending on undisclosed schema details and cardinalities.

`<> ALL (<array>)` is equivalent to `NOT IN (<list>)`, but shorter for longer lists and typically performs better. Both fail when NULL is involved ...

About the more efficient `FILTER` clause replacing the nested `CASE` expressions:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Note the use of `a.ack_no`, `b.ack_no`, and `ack_no` in the inner `SELECT` list. `a.ack_no` is really equivalent to just `ack_no` after left-joining with a `USING` clause. I only spelled it out for symmetry.

`count(DISTINCT b.ack_no)` works, because `count()` does not count `NULL` values - which you get for `b.ack_no` if not present in `bescom_appl_upload_doc`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir... You saved me, still I find hard in understanding your simplified code. But I'll get to understand. Once again thank you so for your time in helping me out.  suggest me some fast way to learn postgresql, if you have any.

Comment: @krickX: I am no expert for that particular question as I started with Postgres in the last millennium. The excellent manual and stackoverflow should certainly help.

Comment: Sure...Thank you