# Combine two queries to count distinct strings with different filters

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by, aggregate-filter

I am trying to write a single Postgres query that will result in a table which looks like this:

```
source |yes_gap|no_gap|
-------|-------|------|
allivet|     29|    25|
amazon |    692|   255|
```

I've been able to write two separate queries, but haven't been able to figure out how to combine them into one.

Here's my query for `product_gap='yes'`:

```
select 
source,
count(distinct(sku)) as yes_gap
from product_gaps where 
product_gap='yes' and
ingestion_date <= '2021-05-25' 
/* aggregate by source */
group by source
```

Result:

```
source |yes_gap|
-------|-------|
allivet|     29|
amazon |    692|
```

And here's my query for `product_gap='no'`:

```
select 
source,
count(distinct(sku)) as no_gap
from product_gaps where 
product_gap='no' and
ingestion_date <= '2021-05-25' 
/* aggregate by source */
group by source
```

Result:

```
source |no_gap|
-------|------|
allivet|    25|
amazon |   255|
```

Can I get both counts in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much faster and simpler with conditional aggregates using the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

```sql
SELECT source
     , count(DISTINCT sku) FILTER (WHERE product_gap = 'yes') AS yes_gap
     , count(DISTINCT sku) FILTER (WHERE product_gap = 'no')  AS no_gap
FROM   product_gaps
WHERE  ingestion_date <= '2021-05-25'
GROUP  BY source;
```

See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Aside 1: `DISTINCT` is a key word, not a function. Don't add parentheses for the single column. `distinct(sku)` is short notation for `DISTINCT ROW(sku)`. It happens to work because Postgres strips the ROW wrapper for a single column, but it's just noise.

Aside 2: `product_gap` should probably be [`boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html).

Comment: thank you it works now, and you're right product_gap should be a bool and would be much easier if it were lol

Answer (score 0):

You did 95% of the work , it just remains to join the 2 sources

```
 SELECT source, yes_gap,no_gap FROM 
       ( select 
    source,
    count(distinct(sku)) as yes_gap
    from product_gaps where 
    product_gap='yes' and
    ingestion_date <= '2021-05-25' 
    /* aggregate by source */
    group by source ) r1
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       ( select 
    source,
    count(distinct(sku)) as no_gap
    from product_gaps where 
    product_gap='no' and
    ingestion_date <= '2021-05-25' 
    /* aggregate by source */
    group by source ) r2
       USING ( source ) 
       ORDER BY source;
```