# Create a report with 2 rows of values, each of which is from a separate SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, union-all, aggregate-filter

I have a report (using [Blazer](https://github.com/ankane/blazer), if you care) that displays data like this, of recently updated or created rows in the `jobs` table:

```
5 Minutes | 1 Hour | 1 Day | Total
----------------------------------
        0        0     367  30,989
```

The SQL looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    WHERE "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minutes' AND NOW()
    ) as "5 Minutes",
    
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    WHERE "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 Hours' AND NOW()
    ) as "1 Hour",

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    WHERE "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 Day' AND NOW()
    ) as "1 Day",

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    ) as "Total"
;
```

I want to add a second row, for jobs `WHERE "Jobs"."active" IS TRUE`.  How do I make this display another row?

I want the final result to be something like this:

```
Status | 5 Minutes | 1 Hour | 1 Day | Total
-------------------------------------------
*                0        0     367  30,989
Active           0        0     123  24,972
```

The labels are not the issue.  The only thing that's not obvious is how to create a new row.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to UNION on another bunch of queries, that have this more restrictive where clause:

```
SELECT
    '*' as Kind,

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    WHERE "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minutes' AND NOW()
    ) as "5 Minutes",
    
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    WHERE "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 Hours' AND NOW()
    ) as "1 Hour",

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    WHERE "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 Day' AND NOW()
    ) as "1 Day",

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    ) as "Total"

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Active', 

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    WHERE "Jobs"."IsActive" IS TRUE AND "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minutes' AND NOW()
    ) as "5 Minutes",
    
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    WHERE "Jobs"."IsActive" IS TRUE AND "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 Hours' AND NOW()
    ) as "1 Hour",

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    WHERE "Jobs"."IsActive" IS TRUE AND "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 Day' AND NOW()
    ) as "1 Day",

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.jobs AS "Jobs"
    WHERE "Jobs"."IsActive" IS TRUE 
    ) as "Total"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would prefer this way to resolve your query:

```
select
  "Jobs"."active" as Status,
  sum(case when "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minutes' AND NOW() then 1 else 0 end) as "5 Minutes",
  sum(case when "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 Hours' AND NOW() then 1 else 0 end) as "1 Hour",
  sum(case when "Jobs"."updated_at" "Jobs"."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 Day' AND NOW() then 1 else 0 end) as "1 Day",
  count(*) as "Total"
from public.jobs AS "Jobs"
group by "Jobs"."active"
```

This way you read your table `public.jobs` once, and not several times (once per `count`). With this choice, grouping by the `status` is a simple `group by` operation

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want conditional aggregation.  In Postgres, that would normally use `filter`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE j."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minute' AND NOW()) as cnt_5_minutes,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE j."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour' AND NOW()) as cnt_1_hour,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE j."updated_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day' AND NOW()) as cnt_1_day,
       COUNT(*) as Total
FROM public.jobs j;
```

You probably don't have future update dates, so this would more simply be written as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE j."updated_at" >= NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minute') as cnt_5_minutes,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE j."updated_at" >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour') as cnt_1_hour,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE j."updated_at" >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day') as cnt_1_day,
       COUNT(*) as Total
FROM public.jobs j;
```

In addition, I would advise you to drop the double quotes from `updated_at`.  Using double quotes around identifiers is just a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing that's not obvious is how to create a new row.

Basically, add a second row with [`UNION ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html).

First get rid of all the separate `SELECT` queries for each metric, though. That's needlessly expensive (important if the table is not trivially small). A single `SELECT` with conditional aggregates can replace all of your original (like Gordon suggested). In Postgres 9.4 or later, the **aggregate `FILTER` clause** is the way to go. See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

To get another row you could just run a another query adding the filter `"active" IS TRUE` to each expression (which boils down to just `active`, as a `boolean` column needs no further evaluation).

But that would double the cost again, and we can avoid that. Run **a single `SELECT` in a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)**, and the split results with `UNION ALL` in the outer query:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE updated_at > now() - interval '5 min')             AS ct_5min
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE updated_at > now() - interval '5 min' AND active)  AS ct_5min_a
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE updated_at > now() - interval '1 hour')            AS ct_1h
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE updated_at > now() - interval '1 hour' AND active) AS ct_1h_a
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE updated_at > now() - interval '1 day')             AS ct_1d
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE updated_at > now() - interval '1 day' AND active)  AS ct_1d_a
        , count(*)                       AS ct_all
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE active) AS ct_all_a
   FROM   public.jobs
   )
SELECT '*' AS status, ct_5min, ct_1h, ct_1d, ct_all
FROM   cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Active', ct_5min_a, ct_1h_a, ct_1d_a, ct_all_a
FROM   cte
```