# SQL - CASE WHEN result outputting conflicting results

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, case

I'm working to solve
https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding/10065-find-whether-the-number-of-seniors-works-at-facebook-is-higher-than-its-number-of-usa-based-employees?python=

This is the query I've attempted to write:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN location = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >
    COUNT(CASE WHEN is_senior = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 'More USA-based'
    ELSE 'More seniors' END AS what_do_we_have_more_of
FROM facebook_employees

Result: 'More seniors'
```

However, when I rewrite it with the conditions flipped around:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN is_senior = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >
    COUNT(CASE WHEN location = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 'More seniors'
    ELSE 'More USA-based' END AS what_do_we_have_more_of
FROM facebook_employees

Result: 'More USA-based'
```

Can someone please explain why there is a discrepancy here? What is wrong with the query I've written?

I know this problem can be solved with sub-queries but I wanted to try out a `CASE WHEN` approach specifically. Is this more efficient?

Edit: the solution I wrote with sub-queries (works with conditions reversed)

```
WITH us_employees AS (
    SELECT id, location
    FROM facebook_employees
    WHERE location = 'US'
),

senior_employees AS (
    SELECT id, is_senior
    FROM facebook_employees
    WHERE is_senior = true
)

SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(location) < COUNT(is_senior) THEN 'More seniors' ELSE 'More US-based' END AS what_do_we_have_more_of
FROM us_employees u
FULL JOIN senior_employees s
ON u.id = s.id

Result: 'More seniors'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.

`COUNT` will count +1 even when your `CASE` return 1 or 0.

`SUM` only count +1 when your `CASE` return 1.

So assume that your table has 1000 rows, then both your two queries will be `CASE 1000 > 1000 THEN ... ELSE...  END`.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `count()` in your query is incorrect. But how do you get different results? Because both counts are the same. So `A > B` is always false, and you always end up in the `ELSE` branch.

A proper query could look like this:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) FILTER (WHERE location = 'US')
               > count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_senior) THEN 'More USA-based'
            WHEN count(*) FILTER (WHERE location = 'US')
               < count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_senior) THEN 'More seniors'
            ELSE 'US-based and seniors tie' END AS what_do_we_have_more_of
FROM   facebook_employees;
```

See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Note, this can never fail with `NULL` values, because `count()` (unlike most aggregate functions) never returns `NULL`.