# How to us CASE WHEN aggregation with bookshelf

Tags: sql, postgresql, bookshelf.js, aggregate-filter, knex.js

I'm working with PostgreSQL and bookshelf and trying to run a simple SQL query in order to get multiple counts in a single query.
This query look like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN date_last_check > (now() - interval '1 MONTH') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as since_two_months,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date_last_check > (now() - interval '7 DAY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as since_one_week,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date_last_check > (now() - interval '1 DAY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as since_one_days
FROM myTable;
```

It seems impossible to do a `CASE` statement in a `sum()` function in bookshelf. I'm tried:

```
return myTable.query(function(qb:any){
  qb.sum("(CASE WHEN date_last_check > (now() - interval '1 MONTH') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as since_two_months")
})
```

And this returns the following query:

```
select sum("(SUM(CASE WHEN date_last_check > (now() - interval '1 MONTH') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)") as "since_two_months" from "myTable"
```

This does not work because of the quotes after the `sum("`).

Does anyone know how to make this work without using a raw query?

Answer (score 0):

I found a poor solution, it's to use knew raw inside the bookshelf query :
return myTable.query(function(qb:any){
qb.select(bookshelf.knex.raw("SUM(CASE WHEN date_last_check > (now() - interval '1 MONTH') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as since_one_month"));
})

Answer (score 0):

Rather use modern syntax for conditional aggregates: the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE date_last_check > now() - interval '1 month') AS since_two_months  -- one_month?
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE date_last_check > now() - interval '7 days')  AS since_one_week
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE date_last_check > now() - interval '1 day')   AS since_one_day
FROM   mytable;
```

See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)