# How to copy the previous row value of the same column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have several tracked specimens that can move between different areas throughout the day (and its periods). In the example below the calculated field `mov` has to restart counting whenever there is a change of specimen or day. If the `period` varies but `specimen`, `day` and `area` still the same then `mov` = previous `mov`. If both `specimen` and `day` remain the same and only the `area` changes then `mov` = previous `mov` + 1.

Like this:

[image]

My questions are:

1. How to copy the previous value of `mov` when period varies but `specimen`, `day` and `area` remain the same?
2. How to increment the value when both `specimen` and `day` remain the same and only the `area` changes?

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.11 (Ubuntu 12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.

Here is what I did so far:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   specimen INTEGER,
   day      INTEGER,
   period   INTEGER,
   area     INTEGER
);


INSERT INTO mytable (specimen,day,period,area)
VALUES 
(1,1,1,1),
(1,1,2,1),
(1,1,3,2),
(1,1,4,2),
(1,1,5,3),
(1,1,6,2),
(1,2,1,2),
(1,2,2,1),
(1,2,3,2),
(1,2,4,3),
(1,2,5,2),
(1,2,6,1),
(2,1,1,3),
(2,1,2,3),
(2,1,3,1);

SELECT
*,
CASE
    WHEN previous_specimen Is NULL THEN 1
    WHEN specimen != previous_specimen THEN 1
    WHEN specimen = previous_specimen AND day != previous_day THEN 1
    -- WHEN specimen = previous_specimen AND day = previous_day AND area = previous_area THEN LAG(mov,1) OVER (ORDER BY specimen,day,period,area) -- **repeat previous value**
    -- WHEN specimen = previous_specimen AND day = previous_day AND area != previous_area THEN LAG(mov,1) OVER (ORDER BY specimen,day,period,area) + 1 -- **add 1 to previous value**    
     ELSE NULL
END AS mov

FROM (
SELECT
*,
LAG(specimen,1) OVER (ORDER BY specimen,day,period,area) previous_specimen,
LAG(day,1) OVER (ORDER BY specimen,day,period,area) previous_day,
LAG(area,1) OVER (ORDER BY specimen,day,period,area) previous_area
FROM mytable
) t1;
```

Comment: Why not add an `UPDATE ... FOR EACH ROW`  trigger that does this as each row is changed?

Comment: Your `period` looks like an incremented number without gaps starting from *1* for every `(specimen,  day) `. Is that so? And always declare your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simpler query should do it:

```sql
SELECT specimen, day, period, area 
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE step)
                OVER (PARTITION BY specimen, day ORDER BY period) AS mov
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , lag(area) OVER (PARTITION BY specimen, day ORDER BY period) <> area AS step
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
ORDER  BY specimen, day;  -- optional
```

If `period` is an incremented number without gaps for every `(specimen, day)`, this is equivalent:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE t1.area <> t2.area)
                OVER (PARTITION BY t1.specimen, t1.day ORDER BY t1.period)  AS mov
FROM   tbl t1
LEFT   JOIN tbl t2 ON t2.specimen = t1.specimen
                  AND t2.day      = t1.day
                  AND t2.period   = t1.period - 1
;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=556a6b59b6d0026dcec02f1af104a581)*

Not sure which is faster. An index on `(specimen, day, period)` would help (a lot) either way.

See:

- [Form groups of consecutive rows with same value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166397/3684)
- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Should be fastest:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)

Comment: It worked very well, thank you. Many things to learn. In real data period is variable and does not start from one.

Comment: @Antonio: The starting point is really not significant for my second query. It just has to be a sequence without gaps. I clarified. The first query works with gaps, too - as long as there are no duplicates.