# SQL to return a row where the count of rows in a table joined by a primary key is an exact number

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have 2 tables:

**savedoutfits**:

| outfitid | param |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| etc | etc |

**accessories**:

| outfitid | assetid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 1 | 102 |
| 1 | 103 |
| 2 | 101 |
| 2 | 102 |
| etc | etc |

The primary key outfitid in both the savedoutfits table and the accessories table is a table relationship.

I am trying to write an SQL query to grab the outfitid's of a row where savedoutfits.param = 'a' and the linked rows in the accessories table contain the assetid's 101 and 102.

So far I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT accessories.outfitid, COUNT(accessories.outfitid)
FROM savedoutfits
LEFT JOIN accessories ON savedoutfits.outfitid=accessories.outfitid
WHERE accessories.assetid IN (101, 102)
AND savedoutfits.param='a'
AND accessories.outfitid=savedoutfits.outfitid
GROUP BY accessories.outfitid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT accessories.assetid)=2;
```

This returns both outfitid's 1 and 2 however as shown in the tables above, outfitid 1 has asset id 103.

How can I write the SQL so it only returns rows which match the exact asset id's in the accessories table and no more or no less along with the param column in the savedoutfits table?

Comment: Always declare your RDBMS and version, please.

Comment: phpmyadmin version 4.9.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregation can be made to work.  We can add another assertion to the `HAVING` clause which rules out the presence of any `assetId` other than 101 and 102.

```sql
SELECT s.outfitid, COUNT(a.outfitid)
FROM savedoutfits s
INNER JOIN accessories a ON s.outfitid = a.outfitid
WHERE s.param = 'a'
GROUP BY s.outfitid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.assetid) = 2 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN a.assetid NOT IN (101, 102) THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Note that I have also switched from left to inner join, which seems to be the logic you want here.

Answer (score 2):

Tested with Postgres:

```sql
SELECT s.outfitid
FROM   savedoutfits s
JOIN  LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct_all
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE a.assetid IN (101, 102)) AS ct_spec
   FROM   accessories a
   WHERE  a.outfitid = s.outfitid
   ) a ON a.ct_all = 2 AND a.ct_spec = 2
WHERE  s.param = 'a';
```

Assuming `accessories(outfitid, assetid)` is defined `UNIQUE` (like seems to be the case).

About `LATERAL`:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Looks like you are running MySQL? Replace the `FILTER` clause with:

```
, count(a.assetid IN (101, 102) OR NULL) AS ct_spec
```

Comment: MySQL supports lateral joins, but `FILTER` is pretty unique to Postgres.  The above won't run on MySQL.