# Calculate rate based on condition using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I want to find the rate of negative and zero profits from a column. I tried to do it using aggregate and subquery but it doesn't seem to work as both method return 0 values.
The code is as follows

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN profit < 0 THEN 1
    END) AS negative_profits,
COUNT(CASE WHEN profit < 0 THEN 1
    END) / COUNT(profit),
COUNT(CASE WHEN profit = 0 THEN 1
    END) AS zero_profits,
COUNT(CASE WHEN profit = 0 THEN 1
    END) / COUNT(profit)
FROM sales;

SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sales
WHERE profit <= 0)/COUNT(profit) AS n_negative_profit
FROM sales;
```

Both query return 0 in values
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HM9Y.png)

Comment: Can you post the table you're working with and the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid [integer division](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE), which truncates (like Adrian pointed out).
Also, simplify with an aggregate `FILTER` expression:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE profit <= 0)::float8
     / count(profit) AS n_negative_profit
FROM   sales;
```

If `profit` is defined `NOT NULL`, or to divide by the total count either way, optimize further:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE profit <= 0)::float8
     / count(*) AS n_negative_profit
FROM   sales;
```

See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing integer division per docs [Math operators/functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html).

> numeric_type / numeric_type → numeric_type

> Division (for integral types, division truncates the result towards zero)

So:

```
select 2/5; 
0
```

You need to make one of the numbers `float` or `numeric`:

```
select 2/5::numeric;  
0.40000000000000000000
```

and to make it cleaner round:

```
select round(2/5::numeric, 2);
0.40
```