# JOIN two SELECT queries with COUNT and derive additional column

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table with the following structure:

```
 name | version | processed | processing | updated  | ref_time 
------+---------+-----------+------------+----------+----------
 abc  |       1 | t         | f          | 27794395 | 27794160
 def  |       1 | t         | f          | 27794395 | 27793440
 ghi  |       1 | t         | f          | 27794395 | 27793440
 jkl  |       1 | f         | f          | 27794395 | 27794160
 mno  |       1 | t         | f          | 27794395 | 27793440
 pqr  |       1 | f         | t          | 27794395 | 27794160
```

I can use the following query to count the total number within each `ref_time`:

```
SELECT ref_time, COUNT (*) AS total
FROM (SELECT * FROM status_table) AS _
GROUP BY ref_time;
```

```
 ref_time | total 
----------+-------
 27794160 |  2259
 27793440 |  2259
```

And the following query to count the total number within each `ref_time` where `processed=true`:

```
SELECT ref_time, COUNT (*) AS processed FROM (SELECT * FROM status_table WHERE processed=true) AS _ GROUP BY ref_time;
```

```
 ref_time | processed 
----------+-----------
 27794160 |      1057
 27793440 |      2259
```

I then try to merge the information using an `INNER JOIN` on `ref_time`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ref_time, COUNT (*) AS total
 FROM (SELECT * FROM status_table) AS _ 
 GROUP BY ref_time) result_total
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ref_time, COUNT (*) AS processed
 FROM (SELECT * FROM status_table WHERE processed=true) AS _
 GROUP BY ref_time) result_processed
ON result_total.ref_time = result_processed.ref_time;
```

```
 ref_time | total | ref_time | processed 
----------+-------+----------+-----------
 27794160 |  2259 | 27794160 |      1057
 27793440 |  2259 | 27793440 |      2259
```

First question: how do I avoid the duplicated `ref_time` column?

Second question: how do I add an additional `percent` column derived as `(100 * processed / total)` (to one d.p.), i.e. to give:

```
 ref_time | total | processed | percent 
----------+-------+-----------+---------
 27794160 |  2259 |      1057 |    46.8
 27793440 |  2259 |      2259 |   100.0
```

Third question: is there a more efficient way to do this? Can I avoid making two separate `SELECT` queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has expressive aggregate functions.

To do the conditional count, we can use the standard `filter` clause directly against column `processed`, which is a boolean. As for the percentage (or ratio), we can cast the boolean to an integer (which yields `0` or `1`, as you would expect), and take the average of that.

So:

```
select ref_time, 
    count(*) cnt_total,
    count(*) filter(where processed) cnt_processed,
    avg(processed::int) ratio_processed
from mytable
group by ref_time
```

Here is **[a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gTth9HpY)** with your sample data, which returns:

| ref_time | cnt_total | cnt_processed | ratio_processed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27794160 | 3 | 1 | 0.33333333333333333333 |
| 27793440 | 3 | 3 | 1.00000000000000000000 |

Comment: Very neat, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ref_time,count(*)as total,
SUM
(
  CASE
   WHEN processed='t' then 1
   else 0
  END
)processed
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY ref_time
```

Comment: Thanks!  What about the second question, i.e. adding a derived `percent` column to the result?

Comment: The CASE Expression can be simplified to `count(*) filter (where processed)`

Answer (score 1):

```
with main as (
    select
    ref_time,
    sum(case when processed = 'true' then 1 else 0 end ) as total_processed,
    count(*) as total
    
    from <table_name>
    group by 1
)
select *, round((total_processed::numeric / nullif(total::numeric,0))  * 100),2) as percent from main
```

Comment: Thanks!  I get `ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY`

Comment: I get the same error as before :-/

Comment: @drmrbrewer it should work now, i changed the issue just now :) try again

Comment: @drmrbrewer can you confirm if its working now ?

Comment: It doesn't give an error now, but the percent is `0` even when `total_processed=1057` and `total=2259`

Comment: @drmrbrewer can you share the code with me which you are running ? all the percent values are 0 or just one case ?

Comment: @drmrbrewer: try `total_processed::numeric / ....`

Comment: @drmrbrewer yess thats the type issue, should be fine now

Comment: i added the `round()` so you don't have many decimal places, is it fine for you now ?, you can also reduce the length of code by moving everything to  one select statement

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT ref_time
     , count(*) AS total
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE processed) AS processed
     , round(count(*) FILTER (WHERE processed) * 100.0 / count(*), 2) AS percent
FROM   status_table
GROUP  BY 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ha0XkPlB)

Returning actual, rounded percentage values.

`avg(processed::int)`, like the currently accepted answer does, is smart but the additional aggregate function plus involved casting adds cost. (The repeated `count(*)` is only computed once.) This is typically faster.

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Aside: "name" is not a good name. Reconsider.

Comment: Thanks for the additional solution and insight.  +1 for "name is not a good name" :-) in my actual table, this column is called `base_name` which I hope is more acceptable!  Regarding "actual, rounded percentages" I was already using `ROUND(AVG(processed::int) * 100, 1) percent` based on the currently accepted answer.  Regarding "the repeated `count(*)` is only computed once... of course I believe you but is it possible to demonstrate this somehow... just curious.  Thanks.

Comment: And of course it's not just `count(*)` that is repeated, but also `count(*) FILTER (WHERE processed)`.

Comment: Incidentally (I'm trying to settle on a consistent convention to use for myself)... why do you not capitalise `count()` even though you capitalise other keywords like `FILTER` and `WHERE`?

Comment: To demonstrate, compare `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM big_table` with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*), count(*), count(*), count(*), count(*), count(*) FROM big_table` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*), avg(some_column) FROM big_table`. Same applies to `count(*) FILTER (WHERE ...)`.

Comment: I capitalize syntax elements and key words of SQL, but not functions (incl. aggregate and window functions). That turned out to work best for me, visually. The distinction gets a bit blurry sometimes, as some "functions" like `COALESCE()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` are somewhat in between.

Comment: Thanks re `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.  And re capitalisation... I can see your logic, because I'm finding that by capitalising everything (except column and table names) it all looks a bit shouty and difficult to read.

Comment: Also, identifiers (including function names), unlike syntax elements, can be double-quoted, and then capitalization makes an actual difference. Unquoted function names are lower-cased  by Postgres before proceeding. So my format is "natural".

Comment: I see, it's nice to have some underlying logic, rather than just being arbitrary/stylistic.  So a function name can be *considered to be* an identifier... or *actually is* an identifier?  I can see that it can be double quoted (like an identifier) but is it *actually* an identifier?

Comment: A function name *is* an identifier. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860

Comment: Thanks... I'd already upvoted that related post of yours, so I must have stumbled across it (and found it useful) in the dim and distant past :-)

Comment: Regarding repeated functions only being computed once, I suppose that you can re-write the query along the following lines so that the function is not repeated as such: https://dbfiddle.uk/DblaQCZU ... is that a valid approach?  Performance is probably the same, but maybe more readable to define stuff and then refer back to those?

Comment: Compared to: https://dbfiddle.uk/83vb0HSe

Comment: Certainly valid, especially for multiple repetitions. Or just with a simpler subquery. My query without either is typically slighly faster.