# Basing OFFSET on another query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, sql-delete, gaps-and-islands

My table structure is roughly as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74339151/4070848):

| name | processed | processing | updated | ref_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | t | f | 27794395 | 27794160 |
| def | t | f | 27794395 | 27793440 |
| ghi | t | f | 27794395 | 27793440 |
| jkl | f | f | 27794395 | 27794160 |
| mno | t | f | 27794395 | 27793440 |
| pqr | f | t | 27794395 | 27794160 |

I created a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gkZW8E8I) already based on this table structure (more on this below), so there is no need to create your own.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74339507/4070848), I am deriving a list of `ref_time` values to use as a basis for deleting 'old' entries from `status_table`:

```sql
with 
    ref as (
        select ref_time 
        from status_table 
        group by ref_time 
        having bool_and(processed)
        order by ref_time desc
        offset 1
    )
delete from status_table s
using ref r
where s.ref_time = r.ref_time
```

But now I want to be more sophisticated about what I use as the `offset`... I would ideally like to keep the most recent `ref_time` for which all records are processed (as per the above example where `offset` is `1`), but the *two most recent* `ref_time` where the second `ref_time` has more associated records than the first (i.e. `offset` needs to be `2` to skip over the two most recent `ref_time`).

I figure that the following query (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74331971/4070848)) will help in this task, because it counts the total number of `processed` records based on `ref_time`:

```sql
select ref_time, 
    count(*) cnt_total,
    count(*) filter(where processed) cnt_processed,
    round(avg(processed::int),2) ratio_processed
from status_table
group by ref_time
order by ratio_processed desc, ref_time desc;
```

So in [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gkZW8E8I) I'd need to preserve `ref_time=27794160` (rather than include it in the delete list as is the case in the example) because, although it is second, it also has a higher `cnt_total` than the first.

In general, the rule is that I want to keep all `ref_time` up to (but not including) the `ref_time` having the same `cnt_total` as the one before (or less).

Comment: Can you edit the second last paragraph to make it more obvious you've included a dbfiddle please? I just went off and created my own without realising.

Comment: In the last example you provide, you have 4 ref_time groups (27794170, 27794160, 27793450, 27793440). Your goal is to delete everything after 27794170 except in the case where the record before has a higher count (in this case 27794160). What happens if 27793450 has a higher count than 27794160?

Comment: @JimJimson you asked "What happens if 27793450 has a higher count than 27794160?".  As per the rule in the final paragraph, if that's the case then we should keep 27793450... but bear in mind that because of the `having bool_and(processed)` in the `delete` query, we're only deleting if all records are `processed`... which isn't the case in this example for 27793450... so we'd keep it regardless of whether or not it has a higher count than 27794160.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH sel AS (
   SELECT ref_time
   FROM  (
      SELECT ref_time
           , count(*) FILTER (WHERE drop) OVER (ORDER BY ref_time DESC) AS drops
      FROM  (
         SELECT ref_time
              , lag(count(*)) OVER (ORDER BY ref_time DESC) >= count(*) IS TRUE AS drop
         FROM   status_table
         GROUP  BY ref_time
         HAVING bool_and(processed)
         ) sub1
      ) sub2
   WHERE drops > 0
   )
DELETE FROM status_table d
USING  sel s
WHERE  d.ref_time = s.ref_time;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ezG3EjF5)

Subquery `sub1` is mostly what you already had. Plus some more:

We only need `count(*)` since `HAVING bool_and(processed)` excludes other cases anyway.

`lag(count(*)) OVER (ORDER BY ref_time DESC) >= count(*)` checks whether the previous row has been same or greater, in which case, we'll call that a "drop". And we want to keep all rows before the first "drop".

So `count(*) FILTER (WHERE drop) OVER (ORDER BY ref_time DESC) AS drops` in `sub2` counts those "drops", and `WHERE drops > 0` eliminate the leading rows we want to preserve.

About this "gaps-and-islands" approach:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

If there can be concurrent writes on `status_table`, you may need to  add the locking clause `FOR UPDATE` to be sure. But you cannot do that in an aggregate query, so you would add another subquery where you do that ... See:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)

Comment: This is great... so many learning points!  As a minor bolt-on, I have a separate DELETE query I run which clears out "old" data based on the `updated` timestamp (hence the reason for that column)... basically I want to keep any `ref_time` that isn't all `processed` (on the basis that it may still be "in process"... hence filtering those out of the existing DELETE list)... but I after some time I can assume that the `ref_time` will never all be `processed` and just delete everything associated with it...

Comment: I have created a fiddle which I think works, to combine my `updated` based DELETE into this one, but I can't help feeling that it's not optimal... what do you think?  https://dbfiddle.uk/z9I7qqeV

Comment: The only changes compared to yours are any instances of `max(updated)` or `max_updated` in the queries.  I don't like the repetition of the threshold `27794395` (prone to bugs when updating one but not another) but since this will likely be in a bash script I can use a variable for that... but perhaps the SQL itself could be tidied up to avoid this repetition?

Comment: Look mostly good to me. Some suggestions: https://dbfiddle.uk/EZOtM6po Or start a new question. Comments are not the place ...

Comment: I could ask a new question but I'm not sure what question to ask, since it's so specific.  The problem I see with your cut-down version is that the "old" (but not fully `processed`) data could mess up the `drops` sequence because they might bubble up into that sequence... hence in my fiddle above I created an `old` column and used ORDER DESC to drop those down to the bottom, out of the way of the `drops` sequence (which should only apply to fully `processed` data).  See the "old" entries with `ref_time=27794165` (not all `processed`) in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/b0xzz-3t

Comment: @drmrbrewer: Sounds like you should just run a simple, separate `DELETE` for the "old" ones.

Comment: OK, seems like good pragmatic advice... this is basically what I'm doing already (i.e. running a separate `DELETE`) and it sounds like it's over-complicating things to try and amalgamate with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple translation into [window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

```sql
with 
 count_per_completed_ref_time as
  ( select 
        ref_time, 
        count(*) cnt_total
    from  status_table 
    group by ref_time 
    having bool_and(processed)
    order by ref_time desc )
,windowed_counts as
  ( select 
        ref_time,
        cnt_total,
        row_number() over w1 as ref_time_num,
        lag(cnt_total) over w1 as preceding_cnt_total
    from count_per_completed_ref_time
    window w1 as (order by ref_time desc) )
delete from status_table s
where ref_time in --only delete completed ref_times, found in the first CTE
  ( select ref_time from count_per_completed_ref_time)
and ref_time not in --prevent deleting these
  ( select ref_time
    from windowed_counts
    where ref_time_num = 1 --top, latest completed ref_time
    or (  ref_time_num = 2 --second latest
        and cnt_total>preceding_cnt_total)--has higher total than the latest
   ) 
returning *;
```

1. Selects your `ref_time` rows same as before, keeping only the ones that are fully processed.
2. Uses a window to show [order](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#:%7E:text=Description-,row_number,-()%20%E2%86%92%20bigint) of these `ref_time`'s, plus the `cnt_total` of the preceding `ref_time`, one [higher](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#:%7E:text=offset%20rows%20before%20the%20current%20row) in this ranking.
3. Always picks the top `ref_time` in this order and if the second one's `cnt_total` is higher, takes it too.
4. Deletes all completed `ref_time`'s found in **1.**, unless they were picked in **3.**, [returning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html#:%7E:text=The%20optional-,RETURNING,-clause%20causes%20DELETE) everything it deleted, for you to inspect.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Z-Ne6uM) with additional test cases.