# Compute averages for two distinct sets from one table in a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query to show the average length of all the proteins which also exists in a second table `mrna_pieces`:

```
SELECT AVG(protein_length)
FROM protein
WHERE exists
(SELECT protein_id FROM mrna_pieces WHERE mrna_brokstukken.protein_id = protein.protein_id)
```

I also want to show the average for all the proteins which don't exist in the second table.

```
SELECT AVG(protein_length)
FROM protein
WHERE exists
(SELECT protein_id FROM mrna_pieces WHERE mrna_brokstukken.protein_id != protein.protein_id)
```

But I want these 2 parts in one table like this
[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbXit.png)
I tried:

```
SELECT AVG(eiwit_lengte) AS avglengthwith, AVG(eiwit_lengte) AS avglengthwithout
FROM eiwit
WHERE exists
(SELECT eiwit_id FROM mrna_brokstukken WHERE mrna_brokstukken.eiwit_id != eiwit.eiwit_id)
WHERE exists
(SELECT eiwit_id FROM mrna_brokstukken WHERE mrna_brokstukken.eiwit_id = eiwit.eiwit_id)
```

But that gives me the following error:

> ERROR: pq: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Comment: Four answers so far and **all wrong**. I added a fifth. Your second query does not do what you want. You'd need `NOT EXISTS` instead. But we can optimize ...

Comment: You need to add a ddl for yourr table with data or a dbfifdle, my answer works fine if your queries have the correct result. Am average without group by returns a scalar value, so please add a  [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be **cheapest** to compute the "exists" value once per row in a subquery, then two conditional aggregates in the outer `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT avg(protein_length) FILTER (WHERE p_exists) AS avg_len_exists
     , avg(protein_length) FILTER (WHERE NOT p_exists) AS avg_len_not_exists
FROM  (
   SELECT protein_length
        , EXISTS (SELECT FROM mrna_pieces m WHERE m.protein_id = p.protein_id) AS p_exists
   FROM   protein p
   ) sub;
```

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause (which can be combined with the `OVER` clause of window functions):

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Or, shorter if two result rows are acceptable:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT FROM mrna_pieces m WHERE m.protein_id = p.protein_id) AS p_exists
     , avg(protein_length) avg_len
FROM   protein p
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Should be slightly faster, yet.

Either way, if your table `mrna_pieces` is big, an **index** with `protein_id` as leading or only column helps performance (a lot).

Note that the second query in your question is not doing what you are asking for. `EXISTS ( ... WHERE m.protein_id != p.protein_id)` is true if at least one row in table `mrna_pieces` does not match, which is always the case if there are at least two distinct values in `m.protein_id`. You would want `NOT EXISTS ( ... WHERE m.protein_id = p.protein_id)`. But use the cheaper query I suggested instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the two at the same time:

```sql
select (
  select AVG(protein_length)
  FROM protein
  WHERE exists
  (select protein_id from mrna_pieces where mrna_brokstukken.protein_id = protein.protein_id)
) as avgwith,
(
  select AVG(protein_length)
  FROM protein
  WHERE exists
  (select protein_id from mrna_pieces where mrna_brokstukken.protein_id != protein.protein_id)
)
as avgwithout
```

Comment: This copies the incorrect 2nd query from the question, resulting in nonsense for `avgwithout`: the avg len of all rows in table `protein`  if at least two distinct values exist in table `mrna_pieces`.

Answer (score 0):

as both queries will gove back a scalar value you can simply use bot as subqueries

```
SELECT

    (select AVG(protein_length)
    FROM protein
    WHERE exists
    (select protein_id from mrna_pieces where mrna_brokstukken.protein_id = protein.protein_id) ) AVG_1,
    (select AVG(protein_length)
    FROM protein
    WHERE exists
    (select protein_id from mrna_pieces where mrna_brokstukken.protein_id != protein.protein_id)) AVG_2
```

Comment: Same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102035/join-2-sql-avg-table-in-one-query/75103681#comment132535146_75102073