# Running Sum of Amount Since Last eligible

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, cumulative-sum, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with users, a month series, a flag for eligibility, a running sum of an amount, and an incremental amount column (example data below). I need to find the amount that has accumulated for each user since the last eligibility flag has appeared.

| User | Month | Eligibility | RunningAmt | new Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Feb 20 | 0 | 150 | 150 |
| 1 | Mar 20 | 0 | 150 | 0 |
| 1 | Apr 20 | 1 | 1000 | 850 |
| 1 | May 20 | 0 | 1200 | 200 |
| 1 | Jun 20 | 0 | 1200 | 0 |
| 1 | Jul 20 | 1 | 1200 | 0 |
| 1 | Aug 20 | 0 | 1500 | 300 |
| 1 | Sep 20 | 0 | 1550 | 50 |
| 1 | Oct 20 | 0 | 1600 | 50 |
| 1 | Nov 20 | 1 | 1600 | 0 |
| 1 | Dec 20 | 1 | 1600 | 0 |

```sql
create table example (
    user int,
    month_series int,
    eligibility int,
    running_amt int,
    new_amt int
);
insert into example
    (user, month_series, eligibility, running_amt, new_amt)
values
    (1,1,1,0,0),
    (1,2,0,150,150),
    (1,3,0,150,0),
    (1,4,1,1000,850),
    (1,5,0,1200,200),
    (1,6,0,1200,0),
    (1,7,1,1200,0),
    (1,8,0,1500,300),
    (1,9,0,1550,50),
    (1,10,0,1600,50),
    (1,11,1,1600,0),
    (1,12,1,1600,0);
```

I have tried many kinds of lag() functions but can't seem to get anything to work. What I want is a column that resets to zero when the eligibility flag is 1 and adds the new amounts in between, essentially:

| User | Month | Eligibility | RunningAmt | new Amt | desired result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Feb 20 | 0 | 150 | 150 | 0 |
| 1 | Mar 20 | 0 | 150 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Apr 20 | 1 | 1000 | 850 | 1000 |
| 1 | May 20 | 0 | 1200 | 200 | 0 |
| 1 | Jun 20 | 0 | 1200 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Jul 20 | 1 | 1200 | 0 | 200 |
| 1 | Aug 20 | 0 | 1500 | 300 | 0 |
| 1 | Sep 20 | 0 | 1550 | 50 | 0 |
| 1 | Oct 20 | 0 | 1600 | 50 | 0 |
| 1 | Nov 20 | 1 | 1600 | 0 | 400 |
| 1 | Dec 20 | 1 | 1600 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT usr, month_series, eligibility, running_amt, new_amt
     , CASE WHEN eligibility = 1
            THEN sum(new_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
            ELSE 0 END AS desired_result 
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE eligibility = 1)
                      OVER (ORDER BY month_series DESC) AS grp
   FROM   example
   ) sub
ORDER  BY month_series;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HsR9aR-N)

Note that we don't need the redundant column `running_amt` at all for this. (Typically, redundant data should not be stored in the table.)

Also note how groups (`grp`) are formed with descending sort order (`ORDER BY month_series DESC`). This avoids an off-by-1 error that would arise from starting each group with the first *0* after a *1*. Counting top-down results in the group numbers we need.

Basics for this query technique:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause (which can be combined with the `OVER` clause of window functions):

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Aside: "user" is a reserved word. You would have to double-quote. But rather don't use reserved words as identifiers at all. Working with `usr` instead.