# How to return latest rows by date for each field

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm on postgres 9.4. I want to query my `adjustments` table for the latest adjustment for each field. Some `adjustments` can adjust multiple fields.

### Example 1

```
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| available_qty | on_hand_qty |  backstock_qty |     date      |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| null          | 2           | null           | 2018-01-03    |
| 1             | null        | 10             | 2018-01-04    |
| null          | null        | 2              | 2018-01-01    |
| 3             | 3           | null           | 2018-01-02    |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
```

...and querying for the latest adjustment for each field would result in:

```
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| available_qty | on_hand_qty |  backstock_qty |     date      |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| null          | 2           | null           | 2018-01-03    |
| 1             | null        | 10             | 2018-01-04    |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
```

### Example 2

```
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| available_qty | on_hand_qty |  backstock_qty |     date      |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| null          | 2           | null           | 2018-01-03    |
| 1             | null        | null           | 2018-01-04    |
| null          | null        | 2              | 2018-01-01    |
| null          | null        | 3              | 2018-01-02    |
| 3             | null        | null           | 2018-01-02    |
| null          | 4           | null           | 2018-01-01    |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
```

...and querying for the latest adjustment for each field would result in:

```
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| available_qty | on_hand_qty |  backstock_qty |     date      |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| null          | 2           | null           | 2018-01-03    |
| 1             | null        | null           | 2018-01-04    |
| null          | null        | 3              | 2018-01-02    |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
```

I can achieve this with a lot of `UNION` queries:

```
(SELECT * FROM adjustments WHERE available_qty IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM adjustments WHERE on_hand_qty IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM adjustments WHERE backstock_qty IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
```

...but is this achievable with one query? In reality, there can be lots of fields here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20748872/11610186 and in your case: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f1a44/5

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Thanks this is getting close! Is there any way to also return the date values for each corresponding field?

Comment: Ideally, I would want the actual `adjustments` row returned

Comment: I put the whole thing in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is what you look for:
(the order is - field, then date when it was latest adjusted)

```sql
select 
   first_value(available_qty) over (order by available_qty is null, date desc), 
   first_value(date) over (order by available_qty is null, date desc), 
   first_value(on_hand_qty) over (order by on_hand_qty is null, date desc),
   first_value(date) over (order by on_hand_qty is null, date desc),
   first_value(backstock_qty) over (order by backstock_qty is null, date desc),
   first_value(date) over (order by backstock_qty is null, date desc)
from
   adjustment
limit 1
```

And updated [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f1a44/15)